# request for member `...' is ambiguous in g++

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, ambiguous

I'm getting the following compile error in one of my classes, using gcc 3.4.5 (mingw):

```
src/ModelTester/CModelTesterGui.cpp:1308: error: request for member `addListener' is ambiguous
include/utility/ISource.h:26: error: candidates are: void utility::ISource<T>::addListener(utility::IListener<T>*) [with T = const SConsolePacket&]
include/utility/ISource.h:26: error:                 void utility::ISource<T>::addListener(utility::IListener<T>*) [with T = const SControlPacket&]
```

Hopefully you can see that `ISource<T>` is a template interface that just indicates that the object can be an informer for an object that is of some matching type `IListener<T>`. So the thing that has me irked is this idea that for some reason functions are ambiguous when, as far as I can tell, they are not. The `addListener()` method is overloaded for different input types `IListener<const SConsolePacket&>` and `IListener<const SControlPacket&>`. The usage is:

```
m_controller->addListener( m_model );
```

Where `m_model` is a pointer to an `IRigidBody` object, and `IRigidBody` inherits only from `IListener< const SControlPacket& >` and definately not from `IListener< const SConsolePacket& >`

As a sanity check, I used doxygen to generate the class hierarchy diagram and doxygen agrees with me that `IRigidBody` does not derive from `IListener< const SConsolePacket& >`

Evidently my understanding of inheritence in c++ is not exactly correct. I'm under the impression that `IListener<const SControlPacket&>` and `IListener<const SConsolePacket&>` are two different types, and that the function declarations

```
addListener(IListener<const SConsolePacket&>* listener)
```

and

```
addListener(IListener<const SControlPacket&>* listener)
```

declare two separate functions that do two separate things depending on the (distinct) different type of the parameter that is input. Furthermore, I'm under the impression that a pointer to an `IRigidBody` is also a pointer to an `IListener<const SControlPacket&>` and that by calling `addListener( m_model )` the compiler should understand that I'm calling the second of the above two functions.

I even tried casting `m_model` like this:

```
m_controller->addListener(
        static_cast<IListener<const SControlPacket&>*>(m_model) );
```

but still get that error. I cannot for the life of me see how these functions are ambiguous. Can anyone shed light on this issue?

P.S. I know how to force the function to be un-ambiguous by doing this:

```
m_controller->ISource<const SControlPacket&>::addListener( m_model );
```

I just happen to think that is terribly unreadible and I would prefer not to have to do that.

Edit... just kidding. That apparently doesn't fix the problem as it leads to a linker error:

```
CModelTesterGui.cpp:1312: undefined reference to `utility::ISource<aerobat::SControlPacket const&>::addListener(utility::IListener<SControlPacket const&>*)'
```

Comment: What is the relationship between SControlPacket and SConsolePacket?

Comment: Can you please add why the last line `m_controller->ISource<const SControlPacket&>::addListener( m_model );` disambiguates the call? If the functions are overloaded they should be in the same class. Where are those functions declared?

Comment: @GRB There is no relationship. Both are structs the derive from nothing. 
@litb I was wrong about that. It made it compile but it turns out to lead to a link error when the linker goes to try to find ISource<...>::addListener(...) which is pure virtual. Now I'm very confused. When you say declared I assume you mean defined. They are defined in the concerete classes that derive from IController.

Comment: @cheshirekow, i mean declared, not defined. Doing "a.B::f" inhibits the virtual call mechanism. Then, a definition for the pure virtual function has to exist if you call it like that. For name-lookup, declarations only are important. A using declaration can stop these ambiguities in that case.

Comment: @litb, Got it. You're spot on. Thanks for the answer as well!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Looks like your situation is like this:

```
struct A {
  void f();
};

struct B {
  void f(int);
};

struct C : A, B { };

int main() { 
  C c; 
  c.B::f(1); // not ambiguous
  c.f(1);    // ambiguous
}
```

The second call to f is ambiguous, because in looking up the name, it finds functions in two different base class scopes. In this situation, the lookup is ambiguous - they don't overload each other. A fix would be to use a using declaration for each member name. Lookup will find names in the scope of `C` and don't lookup further:

```
struct C : A, B { using A::f; using B::f; };
```

Now, the call would find two functions, do overload resolution, and find that the one taking `int` will fit. Carried over to your code, it would mean that you have to do something like the following

```
struct controller : ISource<const SConsolePacket&>, ISource<const SControlPacket&> {
  using ISource<const SConsolePacket&>::addListener;
  using ISource<const SControlPacket&>::addListener;
};
```

Now, the two names are in the same scope, and now they can overload each other. Lookup will now stop at the controller class, not diving further into the two base-class branches.

Comment: NICE! So thats what those things are for. I don't think I ever really understood using declarations (a consequence of not really understanding name lookup). Thank you very much. As a note, I actually put the using declaration in the IController interface. I think that is the appropriate place for it.

Comment: At least in g++, two usings are not allowed. You either choose A::f or B::f in the derived class C.

Comment: @Dingle prolly an old version of g++ - fwiw (for recent users), 4.7.2 handles two usings fine

Comment: Well, a little clarification, what should I do in case of multiple variadic inheritance?

Comment: So why does the standard require the compiler to throw up its arms instead of doing overload resolution in the original case?

Comment: @lb- i guess that's what they thought would be the best compromise in terms if consistency, usability and safety. If you have nested namespaces and in the inner namespace declare a function with the same name as in the outer namespace, they also won't overload (consistency). And imagine if you add a function to a base class whose name matches that of a derived class by chance. May break code that uses the derived class (safety) if the functions overload. Those are guesses only, though.