# Handling variadic templates in c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I have recently started using C++11, and I have read in a tutorial about variadic templates. I have understood that we can define a variadic template like this

```
// example class that uses variadic template
template<typename ...Args> struct mtuple;
```

But how can I handle the template arguments of the `mtuple` class (i.e. how would the `get<int>(mtuple_obj)` look like?)?

Comment: Variadic template magic is really magical, you have to experiment with it, as well as look at many different code samples to see what and why is going on there. [Here is my attempt to write own Tuple class (although don't look at `Tie()` ;D)](https://github.com/griwes/LibRose/blob/master/librosec%2B%2B/tuple.hxx), as one of such code samples, there are also many here, on SO - browse through [tag:variadic-templates] and try to understand them.

Comment: couple of interesting related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7868427/170521 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/7870498/170521

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What `get<1>(t)` looks like will depend on the implementation of `mtuple`.  A typical implementation recusively inherits from a type that holds each argument, so `mtuple<A,B,C>` inherits from `TupleHead<A>` (which has a member of type `A`) and also inherits from  `TupleTail<B,C>`.  `TupleTail<B,C>` inherits from `TupleHead<B>` (which has a member of type `B`) and `TupleTail<C>`. `TupleTail<C>` inherits from `TupleHead<C>` (which has a member of type `C`.)

Now, if you give each base class an integer parameter too:

`mtuple<A,B,C>` inherits from `TupleHead<0,A>` and `TupleTail<1,B,C>`

`TupleTail<1,B,C>` inherits from `TupleHead<1,B>` and `TupleTail<2,C>`

`TupleTail<2,C>` inherits from `TupleHead<2,C>`

Now it's relatively simple to write `get<1>`, because the `mtuple` has a single unique base class of type `TupleHead<1,B>` which can be obtained by an upcast, then return the `B` member of that base class.

[Edit: `get<1>(m)` needs to know the type `B` that corresponds to the tuple element with index 1, for that you use something like `std::tuple_element` which also relies on the recursive inheritance hierarchy described above and uses partial specialization to get the `TupleHead<1,T>` base class with index 1, then determines the parameter `T` in that partial specialization, which gives `B` in my example.]

Many of the techniques used with variadic templates are functional programming techniques, such as operating on the first element of the template parameter pack, then recursively doing the same thing on the remainder of the pack, until you've processed all the elements.  There aren't many things you can do with a template parameter pack directly except count its size (with `sizeof...`) or instantiate another template with it, so the usual approach is to instantiate another template that separates the pack `Args` into `ArgHead, ArgsTail...` and processes the head, then recursively do the same to `ArgsTail`

Answer (score 4):

There is no simple mechanism to iterate over the values of a variadic template. But this can be done recursively. Here is an example:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
void print_values(const char *s, T value, Args... args)
{
    while (*s) {
        if (*s == '%' && *(++s) != '%') {
            std::cout << value;
            ++s;
            print_values(s, args...);
            return;
        }
        cout << *(s++);
    }
}
```

So, if I call `print_values("%d %d %d", 1, 2, 3)` I get this recursion tree:

```
print_values("%d %d %d", 1, 2, 3) // value -> 1, args... -> 2,3
print_values("%d %d", 2, 3) // value -> 2, args... -> 3
print_values("%d", 3) // value -> 3, args... -> NULL
print_values("") // value -> NULL, args... -> NULL
```

I recursively call `print_values()` even when *s == 0 to detect extra arguments

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_templates