# Design pattern, a vector of objects, each of two possible types

Tags: c++, design-patterns, vector, polymorphism

I need to store objects of exactly two types in a vector, the both types have almost nothing in common.

After storing them in the vector, I want to iterate over that vector and perform an action, depending on the type.

my thoughts so far:

- Polymorphism. Overkill, and wouldn't help me much, as I probably would do this:

  ```
  if(dynamic_cast<T1>() != nullptr) {
      ...
  } else {
     ...
  }
  ```
- Merge both types (methods and fields) and add a boolean, representing if its type 1 or 2.

Both patterns seem totally clumsy to me, there is propably a total simple solution, I simply don't see.

The first type is something like this :

```
struct PatternMatch {
  int length;
  int indexInDict;
}
```

The second
one:

```
struct NoMatch {
  std::string rawChars;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you create a `class` that has 2 member variables . One is `PatternMatch` and the second is `NoMatch`. Then create a vector that holds objects of that class ?

Comment: If you use inheritance and virtual functions, then you won't need to do any `dynamic_cast`. In fact, that's what polymorphism is all about (while `dynamic_cast` represents the exact opposite approach).

Comment: Why not have two vectors?

Comment: I think we would need to know more about what you are going to do with these two types to have a hope of spotting an elegant solution tbh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that you have only two types and this number won't grow in future, a *C-ish* tagged union is enough and easy to use:

```
struct PatternMatch {
  int length;
  int indexInDict;
};

struct NoMatch {
  std::string rawChars;
};

struct TaggedUnion {
  enum { MATCH, NO_MATCH } flag;
  union {
    PatternMatch match;
    NoMatch noMatch;
  };
};
```

Now, you can create a vector of `TaggedUnion`s and check the `flag` data member to find out the actual type of each element.

Comment: i avoided unions by now ( was a little afraid of the magic )... but this seems to be the solution to my problem

Comment: @J0hnD0e There is no magic behind unions indeed and sometimes they are useful, so why not? :-)

Answer (score 5):

Use [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/variant.html) or any other *"stack-based discriminated union container"*. I also suggest [visiting the variant using lambdas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7868427/598696).

```
// Either `A` or `B`.
using my_type = boost::variant<A, B>;

std::vector<my_type> my_vec;

// ...`emplace_back` stuff into `my_vec`...

auto visitor = make_lambda_visitor<void>(
    [](A&) { /* do something with A */ },
    [](B&) { /* do something with B */ }
);

for(auto& x : my_vec)
{
     boost::apply_visitor(visitor, x);
}
```

---

Note that C++17 will have [`std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant).

Comment: i also though about visitor pattern, the only problem i cant solve (trivially) with that, is : i want to merge two successive NoMatches into one while iterating over the collection, but i didn't said that in the question