# Define multiple methods with parameters from variadic templates

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I want to define a base template class in a way so that it takes variadic template arguments and defines a virtual method for each argument, where the parameter is the argument type.

E.g. `Base<int, bool, string>` should give me 3 virtual methods: `Foo(int)`, `Foo(bool)`, and `Foo(string)`.

I tried the following:

```
template <typename Param>
struct BaseSingle
{
    virtual void Foo(Param) {};
};

template <typename... Params>
struct Base : public BaseSingle<Params>...
{
};
```

Unfortunately, Foo becomes ambiguous. I can't get the `using BaseSingle<Params>::Foo...` syntax to work. Is there a way?

I know that, alternatively, I can recursively inherit from BaseSingle and pass in the remaining params. Are there perf implications of that?

Comment: Recursive inheritance is normal, e.g. `std::tuple` is implemented that way.  I don't see why you'd get a performance hit, your functions don't even override each other and don't pass arguments at runtime calling overriden member.

Comment: possible duplicate of [using declaration in variadic template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870498/using-declaration-in-variadic-template)

Comment: *Some* implementations of `std::tuple` use recursive inheritance.  But the good ones don't. ;-)

Comment: @Howard http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9641699/why-is-it-not-good-to-use-recursive-inheritance-for-stdtuple-implementations

Answer (score 5):

Here is a suggestion that requires exact type matching:

```
#include <utility>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <memory>

#include <cxxabi.h>

using namespace std;

// GCC demangling -- not required for functionality
string demangle(const char* mangled) {
  int status;
  unique_ptr<char[], void (*)(void*)> result(
    abi::__cxa_demangle(mangled, 0, 0, &status), free);
  return result.get() ? string(result.get()) : "ERROR";
}

template<typename Param>
struct BaseSingle {
  virtual void BaseFoo(Param) {
    cout << "Hello from BaseSingle<"
         << demangle(typeid(Param).name())
         << ">::BaseFoo" << endl;
  };
};

template<typename... Params>
struct Base : public BaseSingle<Params>... {
  template<typename T> void Foo(T&& x) {
    this->BaseSingle<T>::BaseFoo(forward<T>(x));
  }
};

int main() {
  Base<string, int, bool> b;
  b.Foo(1);
  b.Foo(true);
  b.Foo(string("ab"));
}
```

But IMO your own suggestion using recursive inheritance sounds more elegant.

Comment: You need a `std::make_unique` facility :) +1 for that tangled mess in `demangle`. Entertaining stuff

Comment: I tried this, and have `Derived` inherit from `Base`. It seems that `this->BaseSingle<T>::BaseFoo` does not call the overridden Derived `Foo`, but rather calls the base one, which was the whole point of this virtual function business.

Comment: @MTsoul just rewrite it to `BaseSingle<T>* base = this; base->BaseFoo(forward<T>(x));` to get your virtual dispatch back