# Lookup table with constexpr

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

I'm looking to create a lookup table of coordinates, something like:

```
int a[n][2] = {{0,1},{2,3}, ... }
```

For a given `n`, to be created at compile time. I started looking into `constexpr`, but is seems like a function returning a `constexpr std::vector<std::array <int, 2> >` isn't an option, as I get:

```
invalid return type 'std::vector<std::array<int, 2ul> >' of constexpr function
```

How can create such a compile time array?

Comment: `std::vector` is not a literal type and therefore cannot be used in C++11 `constexpr`. C++11's `array` type lacks `constexpr` accessors and therefore also has limited use in `constexpr` functions. If you don't have some of the C++1y lib/compiler support, I suggest using a custom array type instead.

Comment: @DyP - could you show an example?

Comment: Would be more useful if you added some details of what you want to do ;)

Comment: @DyP - Just create a list of coordinates that I'd like to have at compile time. An example would be ~100 points on a line.

Comment: N.B. in C++1y, you can also use an `initializer_list`, as they're [required to be literal types in C++1y](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16063123/420683).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'll dump the code first, adding references and comments where necessary/appropriate later. Just leave a comment if the result is somewhat close to what you're looking for.

Indices trick for pack expansion (required here to apply the generator), by [Xeo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/500104/xeo), from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13294458/420683), modified to use `std::size_t` instead of `unsigned`.

```
#include <cstddef>

// by Xeo, from https://stackoverflow.com/a/13294458/420683
template<std::size_t... Is> struct seq{};
template<std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
struct gen_seq : gen_seq<N-1, N-1, Is...>{};
template<std::size_t... Is>
struct gen_seq<0, Is...> : seq<Is...>{};
```

Generator function:

```
#include <array>

template<class Generator, std::size_t... Is>
constexpr auto generate_array_helper(Generator g, seq<Is...>)
-> std::array<decltype(g(std::size_t{}, sizeof...(Is))), sizeof...(Is)>
{
    return {{g(Is, sizeof...(Is))...}};
}

template<std::size_t tcount, class Generator>
constexpr auto generate_array(Generator g)
-> decltype( generate_array_helper(g, gen_seq<tcount>{}) )
{
    return generate_array_helper(g, gen_seq<tcount>{});
}
```

Usage example:

```
// some literal type
struct point
{
    float x;
    float y;
};
// output support for `std::ostream`
#include <iostream>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, point const& p)
{  return o << p.x << ", " << p.y;  }

// a user-defined generator
constexpr point my_generator(std::size_t curr, std::size_t total)
{
    return {curr*40.0f/(total-1), curr*20.0f/(total-1)};
}

int main()
{
    constexpr auto first_array = generate_array<5>(my_generator);
    constexpr auto second_array = generate_array<10>(my_generator);

    std::cout << "first array: \n";
    for(auto p : first_array)
    {
        std::cout << p << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << "========================\n";

    std::cout << "second array: \n";
    for(auto p : second_array)
    {
        std::cout << p << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow - Thats a lot of code! Is that really the shortest way of doing this?

Comment: @nbubis This is a very general solution. If you narrow down / specify more precisely what you want, there might be a less verbose solution.

Comment: I think he usage example is exactly what I'm looking for,  but that sure is a lot of extra code :)

Comment: @nbubis Short enough now? I realized you don't even need the accessors for this kind of thing.

Comment: +1 [here's what I got](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19023500/819272) before reading  your question (I updated it to make the `make_integer_sequence` opaque to callers, like you did, tnx for that idea)

Comment: @TemplateRex I guess this already has lots of duplicates, I just was too lazy / didn't know what to search for. Is there any significant difference between `decltype(g(..))` and `result_of`?

Comment: @DyP I was just wrestling with the correct syntax, got `result_of` to work before `decltype` :-)

Answer (score 28):

With C++14, you do not need too much template magic. Here an example of how to have a lookup table for `f(x) = x^3` with the first coordinate being the `x` value and the second coordinate being the `f(x)` value:

```
#include <iostream>

template<int N>
struct Table
{
    constexpr Table() : values()
    {
        for (auto i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        {
            values[i][0] = i;
            values[i][1] = i * i * i;
        }
    }
    int values[N][2];
};

int main() {
    constexpr auto a = Table<1000>();
    for (auto x : a.values)
        std::cout << "f(" << x[0] << ") = " << x[1] << '\n';
}
```

Comment: What is the meaning of: `: values()` in `constexpr Table() : values()`? Does it zero-initialize or something?

Comment: &Jonas Yes, it zero-initializes which is necessary because C++ needs to have a compile-const value. It will be set in the constructor later but this is hard to track by the compiler

Comment: @IceFire are you sure? according to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/operator_at non-const operator[] is constexpr only since C++17 version. This therefore can be troublesome

Comment: @DawidPi We do not have an std::array here, though

Comment: @IceFire Ah sure. Sorry for that.

Comment: It may be noteworthy that this approach may cause issues with the compiler running out of heap for sufficiently large `N` which is not that unlikely for large lookup tables.

Answer (score -7):

What about using GNU gperf or some other code generation utility?

Comment: Hi. Would you be able to use gperf to initialize a vector at compile time? And if how so?