# Initialize a static variable shared by only a group of objects C++

Tags: c++, templates, static

I was wondering if is it possible to create a class data member shared only by a group of objects of that same class.

I have a class called *Scene*, and another called *GameObject*,
The Scene creates GameObjects, and each GameObject created must have a reference to the scene it creates it.

I could achieve this by just declaring:

```
class GameObject
{
    public:
        Scene* scene;
}
```

And put whenever a scene creates a gameobject.

```
void Scene::add_game_object(){
    GameObject* gameobject = new GameObject();
    gameobject->scene = this;
}
```

But, this would definitely take a lot of memory.

I was thinking about a solution, ( Currently not compiling but, may be we could shape something from that )

```
class GameObject
{
    public:
        template< Scene* S >
        Scene* get_scene();
}
//
template< Scene* S >
Scene* GameObject::get_scene(){
    static Scene* sc = nullptr;
    if( sc == nullptr ){
        sc = S;
    }
    return sc;
}

void Scene::add_game_object(){
    GameObject* gameobject = new GameObject();
    // link scene and gameobject.
    gameobject->get_scene(this);
}
```

Using it :

```
gameobject->get_scene<nullptr>();
```

Thank you.
Cordially.

Comment: How about having the Scene pointer as a static member of the GameObject class?

Comment: In fact, i can have Several scenes at the same time, and each game object can point to a different but only one scene

Comment: In your game object, you could have an index into an array of scenes.  Using only one byte of memory per game object, that would allow 256 scenes.

Comment: I don't see how the solution you presented is any different from having a static member. Isn't there is still only one `Scene*` for *all* your objects?

Comment: @VaughnCato Quite simple, i will consider your solution.

Comment: @Galik It is one Scene but not the same for all of them. Each group of gameobject would have their own (shared variable) Scene.

Comment: Have you thought about object removal? And 4 or 8 bytes (`sizeof(GameObject*)`) of memory is not that much.

Comment: @slavanap Definitely, The scene manages this,
However, several scenes are active simultaneously and can hold up to hundreds of gameobjects ( scene graph ).

Comment: @Vaughn Cato : your idea is good but I fear that the requested byte may take more than 1 byte of memory. I have no experience of "packed" class ( if possible ) like we used packed struct in plain old C. If for any alignment reason the byte takes 4 or 8 bytes of memory it is not cheaper than a direct pointer to a Scene

Comment: @theVoidZ: it is not the topic of your question but I think your data member scene should maybe more be private and the "this" pointer of the Scene creating the GameObject be passed as a parameter of the GameObject constructor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store the pointer to the `Scene` object in a static variable of `GameObject` even if you have multiple `Scene` objects.

The idea is to have a **separate types** for each `Scene` object as well as **separate types** for their `GameObject`. This allows to have a **separate static variable** for each `Scene` object where the pointer can be stored.

The following code implements this idea. It requires that the maximum number of `Scenes` is set at compile time in order to populate the function pointer table:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// forward declaration
template <std::size_t N>
struct Scene;

template <std::size_t N>
struct GameObject
{
    GameObject()
    {
        std::cout << "created GameObject<" << N << "> which belongs to '" << scene->name << "'"<< std::endl;
    }
    static Scene<N>* scene;
};

template <std::size_t N>
Scene<N>* GameObject<N>::scene;

struct SceneBase
{
    virtual ~SceneBase() = default;
    virtual void addGameObject() = 0;
};

template <std::size_t N>
struct Scene : SceneBase
{
    using GO = GameObject<N>;
    Scene(const std::string& name) : SceneBase(), name(name)
    {
        GO::scene = this;
    }

    void addGameObject() override
    {
        gameObjects.push_back(std::make_unique<GO>());
    }

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<GO>> gameObjects;
    std::string name;
};


template <std::size_t N>
struct SceneMaker
{
    static std::unique_ptr<SceneBase> make(const std::string& name)
    {
        std::cout << "making Scene<" << N <<"> with name '" << name << "'" << std::endl;
        return std::make_unique<Scene<N>>(name);
    }
};

using FunctionPtr = std::unique_ptr<SceneBase> (*)(const std::string&);

// based on http://stackoverflow.com/a/20408889/678093
template <std::size_t N, std::size_t... Rest>
struct FunctionTable
{
    static constexpr auto& value = FunctionTable<N - 1, N, Rest...>::value;
};

template <std::size_t... Rest>
struct FunctionTable<0, Rest...>
{
    static constexpr std::array<FunctionPtr,sizeof...(Rest)+1> value = {SceneMaker<0>::make,SceneMaker<Rest>::make...};
};

template <std::size_t... Rest>
constexpr std::array<FunctionPtr, sizeof...(Rest)+1> FunctionTable<0, Rest...>::value;


struct SceneFactory
{
    auto makeScene(const std::string& name)
    {
        assert(sceneIndex < maxScenes);
        return fTable[sceneIndex++](name);
    }

    static constexpr std::size_t maxScenes = 10;
    static constexpr auto& fTable = FunctionTable<maxScenes>::value;

    std::size_t sceneIndex = 0;
};


int main()
{
    SceneFactory factory;
    auto scene1 = factory.makeScene("first scene");
    scene1->addGameObject();
    scene1->addGameObject();
    auto scene2 = factory.makeScene("second scene");
    scene2->addGameObject();
    scene2->addGameObject();
}
```

**output:**

```
making Scene<0> with name 'first scene'
created GameObject<0> which belongs to 'first scene'
created GameObject<0> which belongs to 'first scene'
making Scene<1> with name 'second scene'
created GameObject<1> which belongs to 'second scene'
created GameObject<1> which belongs to 'second scene'
```

<kbd>[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5df9857b69a247af)</kbd>

Comment: Hello,
It does perfectly fit to the problem, i like it.
However, i will adapt it without the SceneFactory.
Thanks a lot, thank you all.