# Store Tree Object Directly in Source to Avoid Growing at Run-time

Tags: c++, optimization, tree, random-forest

I have 50 (large) decision trees that are currently serialized (in pre-order) as individual, long strings. All of the strings are directly stored in a .cpp declaration file in order to avoid having to read them from a file at run-time.  So, at run-time, a function is called that deserializes each string and constructs its corresponding decision tree using a standard recursive process. Subsequently, a set of features (vector of doubles) is dropped down each decision tree and a class prediction is output. A la Random Forest, a majority vote is taken and final class is taken.

I've tried optimizing the code and have discovered that the re-construction of these large trees takes up the majority (~98%) of my run-time. Thus, I wanted to ask if there were some way to hardcode the entire tree object into the .cpp declaration file. So, instead of having to re-construct the trees at run-time, the tree objects are already available to be traversed at run-time.

Comment: I would be happy to edit my post and provide more code upon request but the code itself has become rather complex and may be beyond the scope of my question.

Comment: Have you considered Cap'n proto - http://kentonv.github.io/capnproto/

Comment: @TomaszKłak: Unfortunately, my boss wants a solution that is completely standalone. Thanks for the suggestion. I'll keep it in mind for other projects!

Answer (score 0):

I you have access to C++11, I think `constexpr` functions are your solution.

You could write functions to generate the data of the trees at compile-time, storing that data in arrays at compile time.

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19016099/lookup-table-with-constexpr) for a working usage example.

Comment: Sorry, no C++11. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @slaw Well, you could write some kind of precompilation script which computes the trees and injects the data into the sourcecode.