# Generate constexpr string table, cannot result in a constant expression

Tags: c++, constexpr

Inspired in https://stackoverflow.com/a/37413361/1734357 I wish to make a string color lookup table of a fixed and known size, so I shouldn't need to template it, but string isn't constexpr

How to go about it?

```
struct Colors
{
    constexpr Colors() : colors()
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < 256; i++)
            colors[i] = "0;" + to_string(i) + ";255";
        for (size_t i = 0; i < 256; i++)
            colors[256 + i] = "0;255;" + to_string(255 - i);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < 256; i++)
            colors[2 * 256 + i] = to_string(i) + ";255;0";
        for (size_t i = 0; i < 256; i++)
            colors[3 * 256 + i] = "255;" + to_string(255 - i) + ";0";
    }
    string colors[4*256];
};
```

Comment: You can't use the `std::string` constructor for `constexpr` expressions.

Comment: `std::string` is **not** `constexpr`.

Comment: (`std::string_view` is `constexpr`, but not sure how much that helps here.)

Comment: @MaxLanghof, it may help, but can't test it as at present I don't have C++17

Comment: @WurmD What C++ version do you have then? 11? 14? 03? Please add the corresponding tag to make sure that any answers actually help you.

Comment: BTW, why only those 1024 and not all the 16M ones? Memory space?

Comment: Here is a great explanation + library to do this (minus the conversion from int) in C++11: https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2017/06/28/compile-time-string-concatenation/

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that to_string returns std::string, and std::string is not constexpr constructable.

This issue can be solved by using [Sprout constexpr library](https://github.com/bolero-MURAKAMI/Sprout). Although you might be disappointed by the compilation time.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sprout/string.hpp>
#include <sprout/array.hpp>
#include <sprout/algorithm/transform.hpp>
#include <sprout/numeric/iota.hpp>

struct colorConv {
  typedef sprout::string<20> result_type;

  constexpr result_type
  operator()(int n) const {
      return n / 256 == 0 ? "0;" + sprout::to_string(255 - n) + ";255"
      : n / 256 == 1 ? "0;255;" + sprout::to_string(2 * 255 + 1 - n)
      : n / 256 == 2 ? sprout::to_string(3 * 255 + 2 - n ) + ";255;0;"
      : "255;" + sprout::to_string(4 * 255 + 3 - n) + ";0";
  }
};

struct Colors {
private:
  typedef colorConv::result_type string;
  constexpr static auto source = sprout::iota<sprout::array<int, 256*4> >(0);

public:
  constexpr static auto colors = sprout::transform<sprout::array<string, 256*4> >(
      sprout::begin(source),
      sprout::end(source),
      colorConv()
  );
};

int main() {
  auto& a = Colors::colors;

  for (auto&& str : Colors::colors) {
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: True but he doesn't have to use operator+ because
"255;" "NUMBER" ";0" is a valid C++ expression

Comment: Literal concatenation and `std::string`? How does this go together?

Comment: Yea I meant not using std::string for colors member variable. He can still use the StringBuilder from the link I posted. He will have access to length and easily construct std::string from const char * if he wants to

Comment: Though, the template machinery you linked might be sufficient. Scaring... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Quite honestly, I'd do this in a Python script, generating a C++ source file (consisting of an array definition) as a pre-build step.

That way, you get the information baked into your application at compile time, *and* the source for the information is still code so easy to modify.

`constexpr` is fine but sometimes you just want to auto-generate some code.

Comment: I once called this generative programming vs. generic programming. ;-) AWK is yet another tool which is useful for preprocessing allowing source code which consists of tab-separated text files (prepared in Excel).