# Convert __m128i value into std::tuple

Tags: c++, c++11, sse, simd

Imagine that, after some SIMD calculations, I get a `__m128i` value with the fourth field with a useless zero value. Is there a simple and portable way to cast the other three fields into a `std::tuple<int,int,int>`, bearing in mind it is not [standard layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9833625/stdtuple-and-standard-layout)?

Comment: "Simple" often conflicts with "portable" and/or "standards-conforming." There's no requirement that a `std::tuple<int, int, int>` have standard layout. However, you'll likely find that most implementations yield a memory layout that is as you would expect. If that's the case, the implementation that you already have in your head would *probably* work, if strict standards compliance isn't a requirement. Since you referenced `__m128i`, you're on x86, so I'm not considering any strange padding/alignment requirements that `int` might have; a `__m128i` is laid out just like an `int[4]`.

Comment: @JasonR: Order of fields of `tuple` is unspecified... so the *"probably work"* is too optimistic IMO.

Comment: @Jason R actually, for SIMD on x86 platform  '_m128' _requires_   alignment(16)

Comment: @Jarod42: Perhaps. The lesson to the OP is probably that no, there's not a portable or standards-compliant way to do this. With that said, there's lots of C++ code out there that isn't perfectly standards-compliant. If you can bound your set of platforms and compiler/library versions, and you're willing to take on the potential maintenance headache in the future, it may be possible.

Comment: @Swift: Not really. A `__m128` is really just an abstraction on top of a 16-byte SSE register. These can be loaded/stored from/to memory with aligned and unaligned memory instructions, so if you have an `__m128` type, it is possible to store it at an unaligned location. With that said, compilers often treat them as having `alignment(16)` when automatically generating code that manipulates them (e.g. when registers spill to the stack). It's a common misconception that you need aligned data to use SIMD on x86; 128-bit unaligned loads have been (mostly) penalty-free for many CPU generations now.

Comment: @Jason R If you would use  _mm_loadu_ps directly,  yes. Presense of penalty really depends  on cache  setup, platform, amount of subsequent operations, etc.  If _mm_load_ps  is used with with  unaligned memory  it would crash and I work on project that mostly runs on quite a number of uneven platforms  (3000 generation of Intel and below) as same time, and benefits from aligned load due to sheer amount of data processed (thing of gigabytes per second)

Comment: @Swift: I work on similar projects. I would encourage you to benchmark changing `_mm_load_ps()` to `_mm_loadu_ps()`. You'll find that for like conditions, their performance is essentially indistinguishable; the choice of instruction you use doesn't really matter. With that said, aligned loads *can* be faster, since they're guaranteed to not straddle cache line or page boundaries, but it doesn't matter which type of instruction you use. Assuming unaligned 128-bit memory operations can simplify your code structure and loosen its constraints on its input and output.

Comment: @Jason R I'll still  have constraint on output, for it accepted by hardware requiring alignment. I think, problem might be in compiler (PGI C++) that uses something slower in case of unaligned intristic. using loadu on aligned data results on spike drops in performance  compared to autovectorized code.

Comment: @Jason R  actually, I looked up, all my platform are either Atom-like or pre-Nehalem,  what you say about is starting appear to be true  with Nehalem and above

Comment: If your SIMD vector is like a 3-tuple, you're probably using an inefficient AoS-based layout with an inefficient lane-wasting calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugly, but portable. I don't believe, that there is fast solution, since `std::tuple` does not have defined memory layout. So just copying those three values into a tuple.

```
std::tuple<int, int, int> to_tuple(__m128i& value)
{
    auto* ptr = reinterpret_cast<int*>(&value);
    return std::make_tuple(ptr[0], ptr[1], ptr[2]);
}
```

---

Why do you need this? Maybe you can get around your problem some other way.

Comment: This is what I was doing, albeit with `_mm_storeu_si128` instead of  `reinterpret_cast`, but I think the resulting assembly is the same. I hoped there was a more elegant solution...