# Is there a way to call libcuckoo's cuckoo_hash_map with keys only (C++)?

Tags: hash, hashtable

Hello smart people of the Internet,

I'm using efficient/libcuckoo library for a c++ project I'm working on. I have a set of uint64_t that I want to store in libcuckoo's cuckoo_hash_map, but so far I noticed that it doesn't let me store them without values (the keys are the only thing I'm interested in hashing).

Is there a better solution in terms of memory efficiency (without replacing the cuckoo hash library or using a Bloom Filter)? Note: I only make use in the keys - I don't need the values.

Thanks in advance!

Solution I:
I create pair<uint64_t, uint64_t> and store the key twice (once as the key and once as the value).
Issue: I spend twice as space and I want to hash table as smaller as possible.

Solution II:
I create pair<uint64_t, Empty> where the first element is my key and the second element is an empty class (Empty e; => sizeof(e) = 1).
Issue: I get better results in terms of the size of the hash table, but I still have 1 byte of unused memory for every key I'm storing.

Comment: As of today, the library doesn't provide a cuckoo_hash_set, so if you need to stick with the library _as is_ you'll have to use one of the approaches you've identified, but with the second approach (an Empty class) you might want to explore the technique mentioned in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13708224/410767 (I've never tried that myself so can't say how well it will work).

Comment: Thank you for answering! I'll make sure to try that.