# std::tuple_element need deep template instantination

Tags: c++11, stdtuple

in here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_element given possible implementation of std::tuple_element.

```
 template< std::size_t I, class T >
struct tuple_element;

// recursive case
template< std::size_t I, class Head, class... Tail >
struct tuple_element<I, std::tuple<Head, Tail...>>
    : std::tuple_element<I-1, std::tuple<Tail...>> { };

// base case
template< class Head, class... Tail >
struct tuple_element<0, std::tuple<Head, Tail...>> {
   typedef Head type;
};
```

But, this implementation need deep recursion instantiation, if tuple has a lot  parameters ( more that 100 or 200 parameters).

Q1: Why C++11 was not added special operator for getting elements by index? 
like tuple[2]  or tuple[0] ?

Q2: Is possible reduce the deep instantiation? For example in D language more template algorithms (in typetuple) needed O(log(N) ) deep instantiation.

EDIT: Q1: Why C++11 was not added special operator for getting elements by index from variadic templates? 
like  template< class ...T> struct index{ typedef T[3]  third_element;}

Comment: "*more that 100 or 200 parameters*" I'm fairly sure no compiler supports tuples with that many parameters anyway.

Comment: @NicolBolas My g++4.8.1 compiles a 300-element tuple created via the indices trick; clang++3.2.1 segfaults somewhere between 150 and 200 arguments (might also be the indices trick, who knows). Had to raise template instantiation depth for both, though.

Comment: @DyP: Fair enough. Though as you point out, it's not exactly the default case.

Comment: Huh, I was sure there was a proposal for random access into parameter packs, but I can't find it. Which answers the question why it isn't there: because nobody proposed it.

Comment: @SebastianRedl: There was discussion about it on the mailing list, but there's no effective way to use such a feature without having some kind of compile-time "static for" construct. Even `constexpr` won't work, since `pack[0]` can have a different type from `pack[1]`. Whatever you use as an index must be a constant expression. And there is no way to loop over some number of things with an index that is a constant expression.

Comment: @NicolBolas At the very least, it should enable a constant-time implementation of `tuple_element`, and a `get` that, while still technically linear in that the compiler has to run a linear overload algorithm, at least has a constant number of template instantiations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why C++11 was not added special operator for getting elements by index? like tuple[2](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/tuple) or tuple[0] ?

First, because even if they did, it'd still work the same way: with recursion. Tuples are primarily a *library* feature. Though they piggy-back off of language features like variadic templates, they were more or less functional in C++98/03.

Second, that *would not be possible*. Not without a *very difficult* language change.

It's not clear what you mean by `tuple[2]`.

If you mean that `std::tuple<int, float, std::string>[2]` should somehow resolve to the typename `std::string`, then that means you now need to explain why this works. Again, tuples are a *library* feature, not a language construct. So there would have to be some language construct whereby `typename[integer]` is a valid construct. What would that be and what would it mean?

If you mean that given:

```
std::tuple<int, float, std::string> tpl{...};
```

We should be able to get the string with `tpl[2]`, that's *several* shades of "not going to happen". C++ is a statically typed language. The only reason `std::get` is able to get away with what it does is that the integer index is not a function parameter; it is a *template* parameter. That is what allows `std::get<0>` to return a completely different type from `std::get<2>`. That can't happen with `operator[](int)`; that function must *always* return the same type.

So now you'd need to have something like `template<class T, int i> ... operator[]()`. And that would be very confusing, because you can no longer do `tpl[runtimeValue]` on that type (since template parameters must be compile-time values). There is no such type where `operator[]` is restricted from being able to work on runtime values. So you'd be creating a *very* oddball type.

And even then... it would *still have to do recursion* to get the value.

> Is possible reduce the deep instantiation?

Outside of compile times (which is not an unreasonable issue), what does it matter? A decent inliner will throw most of them away.

As for compile times, there are [non-recursive implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9643480/734069) of various features of `std::tuple`. Whether they can do `tuple_element` non-recursively, I don't think so. [This libc++ implementation](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/tuple) seems to suggest that [it can't](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/__tuple), despite implementing the `tuple` itself non-recursively.

Answer (score 8):

I think this implementation has O(log(N)) instantiation depth; kudos to [Xeo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/500104/xeo) for the O(log(N)) indices trick (modified to use `std::size_t` instead of `unsigned`).

Edit: I realized there's a different, simpler and probably faster (compilation time) solution to get the nth type of a tuple.

```
// from https://stackoverflow.com/a/13073076
// indices trick in O(log(N)) instantiations, by Xeo

    // using aliases for cleaner syntax
    template<class T> using Invoke = typename T::type;

    template<std::size_t...> struct seq{ using type = seq; };

    template<class S1, class S2> struct concat;

    template<std::size_t... I1, std::size_t... I2>
    struct concat<seq<I1...>, seq<I2...>>
      : seq<I1..., (sizeof...(I1)+I2)...>{};

    template<class S1, class S2>
    using Concat = Invoke<concat<S1, S2>>;

    template<std::size_t N> struct gen_seq;
    template<std::size_t N> using GenSeq = Invoke<gen_seq<N>>;

    template<std::size_t N>
    struct gen_seq : Concat<GenSeq<N/2>, GenSeq<N - N/2>>{};

    template<> struct gen_seq<0> : seq<>{};
    template<> struct gen_seq<1> : seq<0>{};
```

Implementation of / similar to `std::tuple_element`:

```
namespace detail
{
    template<std::size_t>
    struct Any
    {
        Any(...) {}
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct wrapper { using type = T; };

    template<std::size_t... Is>
    struct get_nth_helper
    {
        template<typename T>
        static auto deduce(Any<Is>..., wrapper<T>, ...) -> wrapper<T>;
    };

    template<std::size_t... Is, typename... Ts>
    auto deduce_seq(seq<Is...>, wrapper<Ts>... pp)
    -> decltype( get_nth_helper<Is...>::deduce(pp...) );
}

#include <tuple>

template<std::size_t n, class Tuple>
struct tuple_element;

template<std::size_t n, class... Ts>
struct tuple_element<n, std::tuple<Ts...>>
{
    using wrapped_type = decltype( detail::deduce_seq(gen_seq<n>{},
                                                      detail::wrapper<Ts>()...) );
    using type = typename wrapped_type::type;
};
```

Usage example:

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::tuple<int, double, bool, char> t;
    tuple_element<1, decltype(t)>::type x;
    std::cout << typeid(x).name() << std::endl;
}
```

Thanks to [@Barry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2069064/barry) for pointing out an issue in an earlier version of this answer with function/array types, and providing a fix.

---

Original version:
(Note: This version is simplified and doesn't add cv-qualifiers.)

```
#include <tuple>


namespace detail
{
    template < std::size_t Index, class Arg >
    struct s_get_one
    {
        // declare a function that links an Index with an Arg type
        friend Arg get(s_get_one, std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Index>);
    };

    template < typename... Bases >
    struct s_get : Bases... {};
}

template < std::size_t I, class T >
struct tuple_element;

template < std::size_t I, class... Args >
struct tuple_element < I, std::tuple<Args...> >
{
    template<class T>
    struct wrapper { using type = T; };

    // deduce indices from seq helper
    template < std::size_t... Is >
    static auto helper(seq<Is...>)
        -> detail::s_get< detail::s_get_one<Is, wrapper<Args>>... >;

    // generate indices in O(log(N)) and use name lookup to find the type
    using IC = std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>;
    using wrapped_type = decltype( get(helper(gen_seq<sizeof...(Args)>{}), IC{}) );
    using type = typename wrapped_type::type;
};
```

Comment: @KhurshidNormuradov Try the new version, it might need less resources.

Comment: +1, but this won't work if the tuple contains an array or function type. `get_nth_helper::deduce` should return `wrapper<T>` instead, then `tuple_element` can pull out the `T`.

Comment: @Barry Fixed in both versions, thanks. What do you think about Kurshid's approach below?

Comment: @dyp Clever! I would've made the same comment as you (i.e. make it `base<id<(j==i), T>...>`). I wonder how that compares to the multiple inheritance approach from [here](http://talesofcpp.fusionfenix.com/post-22/true-story-efficient-packing) (search for `_at_index`)

Comment: @Barry See http://ldionne.com/2015/11/29/efficient-parameter-pack-indexing/ My first version is, I think, similar to ldionne's void* implementation, though I'd guess that ldionne's implementation is more lightweight.

Answer (score 4):

```
    template< int ...i> struct seq{};

   // GCC couldn't optimize sizeof..(i) , 
   //see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19783205/why-sizeof-t-so-slow-implement-c14-make-index-sequence-without-sizeof
   //so I use direct variable `s` instead of it.
   // i.e.  s == number of variadic arguments in `I`.
    template< int s, typename I, typename J > struct concate;

    template< int s, int ...i, int ...j>
    struct concate<s, seq<i...>, seq<j...> >
    { 
        typedef seq<i..., (s  + j)...> type;
    };

    template<int n> struct make_seq_impl;
    template< int n> using make_seq = typename make_seq_impl<n>::type;

    template<> struct make_seq_impl<0>{ typedef seq<> type;};
    template<> struct make_seq_impl<1>{ typedef seq<0> type;};

    template<int n> struct make_seq_impl: concate< n/2, make_seq<n/2>, make_seq<n-n/2>>{};

    template< typename ...T> using seq_for = make_seq< sizeof...(T) > ;

//----------------------------------
template< int i, typename T> struct id{};
template< typename T> struct id<0,T>{ typedef T type;};
template< typename ...T> struct base : T ... {};

template< typename ...T> struct tuple{};

template< std::size_t i, typename Tuple> struct tuple_element;

template< std::size_t i, typename ...T>
struct tuple_element< i, tuple<T...> >
{
      template< typename Seq > struct apply;
      template< int ...j > struct apply< seq<j...> >
      {
         // j xor i ==> ( 0 xor i), (1 xor i), (2 xor i ),...(i xor i) ...
         //    =>  i0, i1, ..., 0 (at pos i) ...
         // and only id<0,T> has `type`.
          typedef base< id< (j xor i), T> ... > base_t;
          typedef typename base_t::type type;
       };

     typedef typename apply< seq_for<T...> >::type type;
};
```

Comment: I think you could as well use `template<bool b, typename> struct id{};`, specialize on `b == true`, and then replace the `xor` with a `j == i`. By the way: Really nice solution!

Comment: Thanks, for improving the solution. Really, If I use `bool` instead of `int` - it will more nice solution.