# A generic type trait to non-recursively get the last type of a variadic template?

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, type-traits

### Note:

My concern here is about ***compilation*** speeds.

I assume that recursive type traits are typically slower than the alternatives (when possible). If I'm wrong about this then please let me know.

---

We can access the types at the front of a variadic list without recursion, like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct this_type
{
    using type = T;
};

template <typename T1, typename ...>
struct front : this_type<T1> {};

template <typename ... Ts>
using front_t = typename front<Ts...>::type;

template <typename ... Ts>
void Foo ()
{
    std::cout << std::is_same_v<front_t<Ts...>, int> << std::endl;
}

int main ()
{
    Foo<int, char, bool>();
}
```

However, I can't think of a ***generic*** way to access the back type without recursion. Intuitively I'd want to do something like this:

```
template <typename ...>
struct pack;

template <typename ...>
struct back;

template <typename Tn, typename ... Ts>
struct back <pack<Ts..., Tn>> : this_type<Tn> {};

template <typename ... Ts>
using back_t = typename back<pack<Ts...>>::type;
```

... but the variadic template needs to be the last argument in the specialisation.

We can use a bit of code bloat to manage accessing elements up to a certain amount. eg, 3:

```
template <typename ...>
struct back;

template <typename T1>
struct back <T1> : this_type<T1> {};

template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct back <T1, T2> : this_type<T2> {};

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
struct back <T1, T2, T3> : this_type<T3> {};

template <typename ... Ts>
using back_t = typename back<Ts...>::type;

template <typename ... Ts>
void Foo ()
{
    std::cout << std::is_same_v<back_t<Ts...>, bool> << std::endl;
}

int main ()
{
    Foo<int, char, bool>();
}
```

...But is there a way to do it generically without recursion?

---

### Motivation:

Often we can change the way that we solve a problem so that we access from near the front of a variadic list, but sometimes it's unavoidable to access from the back. I don't want to create useless work for the compiler if there's some language feature that I'm not taking advantage of.

Comment: This is a dupe as far as I can tell. If I've missed something, please let me know, and I'll vote to reopen.

Comment: @cigen, You’re right. Also there’s a promising answer to that question. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I'd leverage `std::tuple` to do most of the heavy lifting.

```
template<typename... Ts>
using back_t = std::tuple_element_t<std::tuple<Ts...>, sizeof...(Ts) - 1>;
```

Comment: Hmm. This is more-or-less what I was doing with my own version a tuple (doh!). However this doesn't quite answer the question. I just took a look at `cppref` and their "possible implementation" uses head-first recursion, so is probably slow to deduce types at the back. (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_element)

Comment: @Elliott you can spelunk your vendor's `<tuple>` to see what they actually do. It's called "possible implementation" not "mandatory implementation" for a reason

Comment: Looking at GCC 10, it does it recursively too. This also doesn't ***quite*** convince me that it's not possible, because *if it is possible* to access from the back then `tuple_element_t` still doesn't have a strong incentive to use it because its users are just as likely  to access from the front (you could use some conditional where if `index > size/2` then access from the back, but this might not be worth it from speed gain given the small additional overhead, especially in small variadics).

Comment: So my question was marked as a duplicate - and some of the answers there show how to get `O(log(n))` recursion in `c++11`, and `O(1)` in `c++17`,  but I think that I should point out that `std::tuple_element` is implemented with recursion in both `gcc` and `clang`  (I haven't checked `msvc` yet) and so should really be avoided until it's fixed. It's extremely slow.. See `Julius`' answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47442393/8658157

Comment: Just FYI, I've since tested `std::tuple_element_t` on `msvc` and it was recursive also - and more importantly, much slower than the alternatives.