# What's a good way to store a small, fixed size, hierarchical set of static data?

Tags: c++, containers

I'm looking for a way to store a small **multidimensional** set of data which is known at compile time and never changes. The purpose of this structure is to act as a global constant that is stored within a single namespace, but otherwise globally accessible *without instantiating an object*.

If we only need one level of data, there's a bunch of ways to do this. You could use an `enum` or a `class` or `struct` with static/constant variables:

```
class MidiEventTypes{
   public:
   static const char NOTE_OFF = 8;
   static const char NOTE_ON = 9;
   static const char KEY_AFTERTOUCH = 10;
   static const char CONTROL_CHANGE = 11;
   static const char PROGRAM_CHANGE = 12;
   static const char CHANNEL_AFTERTOUCH = 13;
   static const char PITCH_WHEEL_CHANGE = 14;
};
```

We can easily compare a numeric variable anywhere in the program by using this class with it's members:

```
char nTestValue = 8;
if(nTestValue == MidiEventTypes::NOTE_OFF){} // do something...
```

But what if we want to store more than just a name and value pair? What if we also want to store some *extra* data with **each** constant? In our example above, let's say we also want to store the number of bytes that must be read for each event type.

Here's some pseudo code usage:

```
char nTestValue = 8;
if(nTestValue == MidiEventTypes::NOTE_OFF){
   std::cout << "We now need to read " << MidiEventTypes::NOTE_OFF::NUM_BYTES << " more bytes...." << std::endl;
}
```

We should also be able to do something like this:

```
char nTestValue = 8;
// Get the number of read bytes required for a MIDI event with a type equal to the value of nTestValue.
char nBytesNeeded = MidiEventTypes::[nTestValue]::NUM_BYTES;
```

Or alternatively:

```
char nTestValue = 8;    
char nBytesNeeded = MidiEventTypes::GetRequiredBytesByEventType(nTestValue);
```

and:

```
char nBytesNeeded = MidiEventTypes::GetRequiredBytesByEventType(NOTE_OFF);
```

This question isn't about how to make *instantiated* classes do this. I can do that already. The question is about how to store and access "extra" constant (unchanging) data that is related/attached to a constant. (This structure isn't required at runtime!) Or how to create a multi-dimensional constant. It seems like this could be done with a static class, but I've tried several variations of the code below, and each time the compiler found something different to complain about:

```
static class MidiEventTypes{
   
   public:
   static const char NOTE_OFF = 8;
   static const char NOTE_ON = 9;
   static const char KEY_AFTERTOUCH = 10; // Contains Key Data
   static const char CONTROL_CHANGE = 11; // Also: Channel Mode Messages, when special controller ID is used.
   static const char PROGRAM_CHANGE = 12;
   static const char CHANNEL_AFTERTOUCH = 13;
   static const char PITCH_WHEEL_CHANGE = 14;
   
   // Store the number of bytes required to be read for each event type.
   static std::unordered_map<char, char> BytesRequired = {
      {MidiEventTypes::NOTE_OFF,2},
      {MidiEventTypes::NOTE_ON,2},
      {MidiEventTypes::KEY_AFTERTOUCH,2},
      {MidiEventTypes::CONTROL_CHANGE,2},
      {MidiEventTypes::PROGRAM_CHANGE,1},
      {MidiEventTypes::CHANNEL_AFTERTOUCH,1},
      {MidiEventTypes::PITCH_WHEEL_CHANGE,2},
   };
   
   static char GetBytesRequired(char Type){
      return MidiEventTypes::BytesRequired.at(Type);
   }
   
};
```

This specific example doesn't work because it won't let me create a `static unordered_map`. If I don't make the `unordered_map` `static`, then it compiles but `GetBytesRequired()` can't *find* the map. If I make `GetBytesRequired()` non-static, it can find the map, but then I can't call it without an instance of `MidiEventTypes` and I don't want instances of it.

Again, this question isn't about how to fix the compile errors, the question is about what is the appropriate structure and design pattern for storing static/constant data that is more than a key/value pair.

These are the goals:

- Data and size is known at compile time and never changes.
- Access a small set of data with a human readable key to each set. The key should
  map to a specific, non-linear integer.
- Each data set contains the same member data set. ie. Each `MidiEventType` has a `NumBytes` property.
- Sub-items can be accessed with a named key or function.
- With the key, (or a variable representing the key's value), we should
  be able to read extra data associated with the constant item that the key
  points to, using another named key for the extra data.
- We should not need to instantiate a class to read this data, as
  nothing changes, and there should not be more than one copy of the
  data set.
- In fact, other than an include directive, nothing should be required to access the data, because it should behave like a constant.
- We don't need this object at runtime. The goal is to make the code more organized and easier to read by storing groups of data with a named label structure, rather than using (ambiguous) integer literals everywhere.
- It's a constant that you can drill down into... like JSON.
- Ideally, casting should not be required to use the value of the constant.
- We should avoid redundant lists that repeat data and can get out of sync. For example, once we define that `NOTE_ON = 9`, The literal `9` should not appear anywhere else. The label `NOTE_ON` should be used instead, so that the value can be changed in only one place.
- This is a generic question, MIDI is just being used as an example.
- Constants should be able to have more than one property.

What's the best way to store a small, fixed size, hierarchical (multidimensional) set of static data which is known at compile time, with the same use case as a constant?

Comment: this is largely opinion based. Though, I would use an `enum MidiEventType` which acts just as a key for a `const std::unordered_map<MidiEventType,MidiEventData>` and instead of keeping seperate fields for the data it is all in `MidiEventData`

Comment: Works for me with some modifications: https://ideone.com/Evm7Dg Unless you're really scraping for a few bytes I'd make the byte value an int.

Comment: There is one dimension, many properties, not many dimensions.

Comment: Typical would be a plain array, I think.

Comment: @Nick have you looked at library-versions of what you're doing? Something like https://github.com/serge-sans-paille/frozen?

Comment: You say this structure isn't required at runtime, but show example code where you're looking up properties from a non-`constexpr` key. Do you need the runtime lookups you sketched? Or will you actually always use the literal constant key (`NOTE_ON` etc.)?

Comment: @Useless: We need to be able to use an integer type variable that which represents a number from 8-14, at runtime, as it parses a file or stream. What doesn't change is that the number of additional bytes to read and other data we may wish to store, will always be the same for any given key (which represents an event type). ie. 8=>2, 9=>2,12=>1, etc. Each integer key represents a type, and each type has a fixed set of data associated with it. There is a finite list of types that don't change and a finite list of type properties, which are different for each type, but  do not change at runtime.

Comment: @FlorianHumblot: That is interesting and I will investigate more. Although standard library solutions are preferred if there is a good way of doing it.

Comment: The C++ standard has added many new options for compile time code and data. You should specify which standard you are using, as this will effect the chosen solution.

Comment: @Tiger4Hire: `gcc --version` is `gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110`. Looking through the features on the official site (https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx20), it seems that I can't say for certain which C++ standard is used. It says there is *experimental* support for C++20, and C++23, but it requires a command line switch, and I'm not sure if/how that switch can be used from within the CodeLite IDE. It also says gcc "has almost full support" for C++17. So it seems that support is on a per-feature basis, rather than a complete and absolute version of the standard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is my take on it, a full constexpr compile time solution.
For your use also put the midi stuff in a header file and you're good to go.

With header files https://www.onlinegdb.com/lGp7zMNB6

```
#include <iostream>
#include "const_string.h"
#include "const_map.h"

namespace midi
{
    using data_t = char;
    using string_t = const_string<32>; // 32 is big enough to hold strings in map

    namespace control
    {
        constexpr data_t NOTE_OFF = 8;
        constexpr data_t NOTE_ON = 9;
        constexpr data_t KEY_AFTERTOUCH = 10;
        constexpr data_t CONTROL_CHANGE = 11;
        constexpr data_t PROGRAM_CHANGE = 12;
        constexpr data_t CHANNEL_AFTERTOUCH = 13;
        constexpr data_t PITCH_WHEEL_CHANGE = 14;
    } /* namespace control */

    constexpr auto required_bytes = make_const_map<data_t, data_t>({
        {control::NOTE_OFF,2},
        {control::NOTE_ON,2},
        {control::KEY_AFTERTOUCH,2},
        {control::CONTROL_CHANGE,2},
        {control::PROGRAM_CHANGE,1},
        {control::CHANNEL_AFTERTOUCH,1},
        {control::PITCH_WHEEL_CHANGE,2}
    });

    constexpr auto str = make_const_map<data_t, string_t>({
        { control::NOTE_ON,"Note on" },
        { control::NOTE_OFF,"Note off" },
        { control::CONTROL_CHANGE, "Control change"},
        { control::CHANNEL_AFTERTOUCH, "Channel aftertouch"},
        { control::PITCH_WHEEL_CHANGE, "Pitch wheel change"}
    });

} /* namespace midi */

int main()
{
    static_assert(midi::control::NOTE_OFF == 8, "test failed");
    static_assert(midi::required_bytes[midi::control::NOTE_OFF] == 2, "test failed");
    static_assert(midi::required_bytes[13] == 1, "test failed");
    static_assert(midi::str[midi::control::NOTE_OFF] == "Note off", "test failed");

    return 0;
}
```

// Edit after acceptance : cleaner syntax

```
#include <iostream>
#include "const_string.h"
#include "const_map.h"

namespace midi_details
{
    using data_t = char;
    using string_t = const_string<32>;
}

constexpr midi_details::data_t MIDI_NOTE_OFF = 8;
constexpr midi_details::data_t MIDI_NOTE_ON = 9;
constexpr midi_details::data_t MIDI_KEY_AFTERTOUCH = 10;
constexpr midi_details::data_t MIDI_CONTROL_CHANGE = 11;
constexpr midi_details::data_t MIDI_PROGRAM_CHANGE = 12;
constexpr midi_details::data_t MIDI_CHANNEL_AFTERTOUCH = 13;
constexpr midi_details::data_t MIDI_PITCH_WHEEL_CHANGE = 14;

namespace midi_details
{
    constexpr auto required_bytes = make_const_map<data_t, data_t>({
        {MIDI_NOTE_OFF,2},
        {MIDI_NOTE_ON,2},
        {MIDI_KEY_AFTERTOUCH,2},
        {MIDI_CONTROL_CHANGE,2},
        {MIDI_PROGRAM_CHANGE,1},
        {MIDI_CHANNEL_AFTERTOUCH,1},
        {MIDI_PITCH_WHEEL_CHANGE,2}
        });

    constexpr auto str = make_const_map<data_t, string_t>({
            { MIDI_NOTE_ON,"Note on" },
            { MIDI_NOTE_OFF,"Note off" },
            { MIDI_CONTROL_CHANGE, "Control change"},
            { MIDI_CHANNEL_AFTERTOUCH, "Channel aftertouch"},
            { MIDI_PITCH_WHEEL_CHANGE, "Pitch wheel change"}
        });

    struct info_t
    {
        constexpr info_t(data_t r, string_t n) :
            required_bytes{ r },
            name{ n }
        {
        }

        data_t  required_bytes;
        string_t name;
    };

} /* namespace midi_details */

constexpr auto midi(midi_details::data_t value)
{
    return midi_details::info_t{ midi_details::required_bytes[value], midi_details::str[value] };
}

int main()
{
    static_assert(MIDI_NOTE_OFF == 8);
    static_assert(midi(MIDI_NOTE_OFF).required_bytes == 2, "test failed");
    static_assert(midi(MIDI_NOTE_OFF).name == "Note off", "test failed");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I like this because it keeps it clean and simple. But where can I find out more about `const_map.h` and `make_const_map`? Which library is that a part of?

Comment: Yes, that works, thanks! I'm going to go through it now and make sure I understand how it works. :)

Comment: If you find anything let me know, happy to clarify. 
It isn't up to full production quality yet (not all types work and there is no type checking, just ugly compiler errors). But works good enough with other constexpr types for now.

Comment: line 72 of const_map is a bit of a shortcut. It works because the equality operator of the key value pair only checks the key part. It slightly breaks my own rule about "no tricks".

Comment: If you haven't already, you might want to look at this: https://github.com/lefticus/constexpr_all_the_things and the presentation that went with it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PJwd4JLYJJY. I came across this in my own search for answers, but I haven't gone through the code yet. It's an attempt at making a `constexpr` JSON (style) tree and parser in C++.

Comment: Is there a way to access the data in a more hierarchical way, where bytes_required is a property of the event type, rather than a function that takes the event type? If it were possible without a lot of complexity and overhead, the ideal syntax would be something like: `MIDI::EVENTS[NOTE_ON]; // 9` and `MIDI::EVENTS[NOTE_ON]::BYTES_REQUIRED; // 2` and finally `MIDI::EVENTS[9]::BYTES_REQUIRED;` for lookup using an int derived at runtime while parsing. I'm thinking that if `namespace control` were a class instead, there might be a way to make `bytes` and the `name` string accessible as members.

Comment: ::BYTES_REQUIRED syntax would require static variables, which would move evaluation to runtime. So I don't think so. For now this is the cleanest solution I could come up with.

Comment: @Nick Oops I see I did not add the correct link for this updated syntax    **static_assert(midi(MIDI_NOTE_OFF).required_bytes == 2, "test failed");**, the link is https://onlinegdb.com/lGp7zMNB6

Answer (score 3):

How about something like:

```
struct MidiEventType
{
    char value;
    char byteRequired; // Store the number of bytes required to be read
};

struct MidiEventTypes{
   static constexpr MidiEventType NOTE_OFF { 8, 2};
   static constexpr MidiEventType NOTE_ON { 9, 2};
   static constexpr MidiEventType KEY_AFTERTOUCH { 10, 2};
   static constexpr MidiEventType CONTROL_CHANGE { 11, 2};
   static constexpr MidiEventType PROGRAM_CHANGE  { 12, 1};
   static constexpr MidiEventType CHANNEL_AFTERTOUCH { 13, 1};
   static constexpr MidiEventType PITCH_WHEEL_CHANGE { 14, 2};
};
```

Comment: I think this would require some type of operator overloading so that `MidiEventTypes::NOTE_OFF` returns the `value` property of it's `MidiEventType`. Otherwise you get something like, `could not convert 'MidiEventTypes::NOTE_OFF' from 'const MidiEventType' to 'int'`, because it doesn't know to use `value` in comparison operators.

Comment: @Nick: I would have used `NOTE_OFF.value`, but `consexpr operator char() const { return value; }` should be an alternative to have your syntax.

Comment: Thanks! So that works with comparing the values. But when going the other way, how can I access the member property `byteRequired` with an int variable that represents a value? If we have `int nEventType = 8;`, then we need to use that EventType value to get the data, like: `int BytesRqd = MidiEventTypes::[nEventType].nBytesRequired;`

Comment: `NOTE_OFF.byteRequired`? You can also have `static constexpr std::array<MidiEventType , 7> {NOTE_OFF, NOTE_ON, KEY_AFTERTOUCH, ..}` if you want to do some look-up/find.

Comment: This seems like the best solution to me. We could event make it event more concise [like this](https://godbolt.org/z/bEqqPYhK3). We could easily add in something to access `value` another way, but I don't understand why we'd want to.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my take using templates. I'm using `int` instead of `char` but you can change these to suit your needs. Live code [here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8861ff9384eb45ff)

```
#include <iostream>

template <int V, int B>
struct MidiEventType
{
    static constexpr int value = V;

    static constexpr int bytes = B;

    constexpr operator int() const
    {
        return V;
    }
};

// dummy classes, used for accessing a given property from MidiEventType
// create as many as the number of properties in MidiEventType and specialize GetProperty for each
struct Value;
struct Bytes;

template <class T, class Property>
struct GetProperty;

template <class T>
struct GetProperty<T, Value>
{
    static constexpr auto property = T::value;
};

template <class T>
struct GetProperty<T, Bytes>
{
    static constexpr auto property = T::bytes;
};

struct MidiEventTypes
{
    static constexpr MidiEventType<8,2> NOTE_OFF{};
    static constexpr MidiEventType<9,2> NOTE_ON{};
    static constexpr MidiEventType<10,2> KEY_AFTERTOUCH{};
    static constexpr MidiEventType<11,2> CONTROL_CHANGE{};
    static constexpr MidiEventType<12,1> PROGRAM_CHANGE{};
    static constexpr MidiEventType<13,1> CHANNEL_AFTERTOUCH{};
    static constexpr MidiEventType<14,2> PITCH_WHEEL_CHANGE{};
    static constexpr MidiEventType<-1,-1> INVALID{};

    // perform the lookup
    template <class Property>
    static constexpr auto get(int key)
    {
        return get_impl<Property, decltype(NOTE_OFF), decltype(NOTE_ON),
                decltype (KEY_AFTERTOUCH), decltype (CONTROL_CHANGE),
                decltype (PROGRAM_CHANGE), decltype (CHANNEL_AFTERTOUCH),
                decltype (PITCH_WHEEL_CHANGE)>::call(key);
    }

private:

    // class to automate the construction of if/else branches when looking up the key
    // our template parameters here will be MidiEventType<X,Y>
    template <class Property, class T, class... Rest>
    struct get_impl
    {
        static constexpr auto call(int key)
        {
            if(T::value == key) return GetProperty<T, Property>::property;
            else return get_impl<Property, Rest...>::call(key);
        }
    };

    // specialization for a single class
    // if the key is not found then return whatever we've set for the INVALID type
    template <class Property, class T>
    struct get_impl<Property, T>
    {
        static constexpr auto call(int key)
        {
            if(T::value == key) return GetProperty<T, Property>::property;
            else return GetProperty<decltype(INVALID), Property>::property;
        }
    };
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << MidiEventTypes::CHANNEL_AFTERTOUCH.bytes << std::endl;
    std::cout << MidiEventTypes::get<Value>(MidiEventTypes::NOTE_OFF) << std::endl;
    std::cout << MidiEventTypes::get<Bytes>(MidiEventTypes::CHANNEL_AFTERTOUCH) << std::endl;
    std::cout << MidiEventTypes::get<Bytes>(42) << std::endl; // invalid key, return INVALID.bytes
}
```

Comment: This seems like an appropriate solution although I'd put the `get` function and the members in a macro to make sure you don't accidentally miss one. +1 either way

Answer (score 1):

Lots of good clever solutions here for sure, though I feel like someone needs to offer to represent the simple approach. As long as you can get by without needing to literally always use square brackets to look up metadata, you can just use a switch statement in a `constexpr` function. Here's my solution:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace MidiEvents {

struct MidiEventMetaData {
    int num_bytes;
    const char *str;
    uint32_t stuff;
};

enum MidiEventTypes {
   NOTE_OFF = 8,
   NOTE_ON = 9,
   KEY_AFTERTOUCH = 10,
   CONTROL_CHANGE = 11,
   PROGRAM_CHANGE = 12,
   CHANNEL_AFTERTOUCH = 13,
   PITCH_WHEEL_CHANGE = 14,
   OTHER = 17
};

constexpr MidiEventMetaData get(char event_type)
{
    switch (event_type) {
    default:
        break;
    case NOTE_OFF:
        return { 1, "note off", 7 }; 
    case NOTE_ON:
        return { 1, "note on", 20 }; 
    case KEY_AFTERTOUCH:
        return { 2, "aftertouch", 100 };
    }
    return { 0, "unknown", 0 };
}

constexpr char GetRequiredBytesByEventType(char event_type)
{
    return get(event_type).num_bytes;
}

constexpr const char *GetEventNameByType(char event_type)
{
    return get(event_type).str;
}

} // namespace MidiEvents

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char num_bytes = MidiEvents::GetRequiredBytesByEventType(MidiEvents::KEY_AFTERTOUCH);
    const char * const name = MidiEvents::GetEventNameByType(MidiEvents::KEY_AFTERTOUCH);
    std::cout << "name = " << name << "\n"; 
    std::cout << "num_bytes = " << (int)num_bytes << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The one caveat is that in practice, the compiler won't collapse all of this to actual constants until you build with `-O2`. Check it out on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/qcqW5h5Yj). You can clearly see the main function is just calls to `cout`, passing in constant values. If you remove the `-O2`, that will no longer be the case.

The advantage here is that this code is very close to what you would write in the most simplistic of scenarios. It's understandable by pretty much everyone, requires the absolute minimum of non-volatile storage, and has no restriction on event value ordering, etc.

Comment: +1 for posting the simple answer. I like that it uses the standard library. As I said in another comment, I feel like soon there will be some kind of `constexpr JSON` object in the standard library, since there seems to be interest in something like that, and some proposals to that effect.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution:

First we make a generic mapper to types, `map_t`. We do this by requiring that each type (mapped to) has a `static constexpr` value named `key`:

```
template <auto, auto, typename>
struct type_if_equal {};

template <auto k, typename T>
struct type_if_equal <k, k, T> : T {};

template <auto k, typename ... Ts>
struct map_t : type_if_equal<k, Ts::key, Ts>... {};
```

For the OP's problem, we put the data into a `struct` along with its associated `Event` as the `key`. Finally we wrap it into something user-friendly with `using`:

```
struct Midi {

    enum class Event : char {
        NOTE_OFF = 8,
        NOTE_ON,    // +1 till specified
        KEY_AFTERTOUCH,
        CONTROL_CHANGE,
        PROGRAM_CHANGE,
        CHANNEL_AFTERTOUCH,
        PITCH_WHEEL_CHANGE
    };
    
private:
    // D = Data (shortened for re-use in mapping)
    template <Event e, int bytes /* other data */ >
    struct D {
        constexpr static Event key = e;
        constexpr static int BytesRequired = bytes;
        /* store other data here */
    };
    
public:
    
    template <Event e>
    using Info = map_t<e,
        D<Event::NOTE_OFF, 2>,
        D<Event::NOTE_ON, 2>,
        D<Event::KEY_AFTERTOUCH, 2>,
        D<Event::CONTROL_CHANGE, 2>,
        D<Event::PROGRAM_CHANGE, 1>,
        D<Event::CHANNEL_AFTERTOUCH, 1>,
        D<Event::PITCH_WHEEL_CHANGE, 2>>;
};
```

Demos:

- [C++17](https://godbolt.org/z/9Kcos8Khd)
- [C++11](https://godbolt.org/z/43sxbd4dc) (no `auto`)

We effectively end up with a type "array" called `Info` which takes in any `Event` type and gives us the appropriate `Data` type (with the `static` data that we care about).

---

### Generality of solution:

Some of the other answers here are ***much*** better (simpler yet still effective) for the specific example problem given. However, the OP has asked for something more generic than the example problem.

I think the idea here is that we may want to use meta-programming (MP) to deduce an `event` value, ***then*** to access the appropriate data we'd need something that actually takes the `event` in as a variable, not just a name (I think this is the functionality that the OP was interested in). We could make our MP reliant on the data collection, but this has more coupling - and what if we didn't write the MP code?

In this answer I assume that the `Key` type ***cannot*** be changed to make it work nicely for the mapping. I also don't assume that the keys are going to have nice ordering to make for simple mappings: for the OP we could just map `array[event - 8]`, but this isn't a generic solution.

This is a niche solution to a niche problem. Note that I list the `Event` elements twice - not by necessity - but because I'm demonstrating the separation of key definitions and the mapping.

---

### Explanation:

Intuitively an array seems like the simplest option, but I wanted to avoid generating a mapping of indices. Instead we use the compiler's native mapping. Originally my answer was like so:

```
template <int b /* other data */ >
struct Data {
    constexpr static int BytesRequired = b;
    /* store other data here */
};

template <Event>
struct Info {};

// Specify mappings:
template <>
struct Info <Event::NOTE_OFF> : Data<2> {};

template <>
struct Info <Event::NOTE_ON> : Data<2> {};

template <>
struct Info <Event::KEY_AFTERTOUCH> : Data<2> {};

// ...
```

... But I wanted to avoid the repetitive style, so I used "conditional" multi-inheritance with [pack expansion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) which effectively generates a list like above. I first saw this wonderful trick [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47442393/8658157). It might seem strange at first, but it's common in meta-programming, and it's surprisingly efficient for the compiler (much better than recursion), and of course, has no run-time overhead.

Comment: *"The idea here is that we may want to use meta-programming to deduce an event value, then to access the appropriate data we'd need something that actually takes the event in as a variable, not just a name..."* That's correct. +1 for lots of good info here. I feel like what I'm trying to do will be trivial in a future version of C++, since it seems that (from watching CPPcon talks like "constexpr all the things") that there is interest in static data structures, but the `STD` library needs some tweaking and development to make it all work.

Answer (score 0):

Just write `constexpr` code to access that. This my very chaotic example:

```
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

enum class MidiEvents {
   NOTE_OFF,
   NOTE_ON,
   KEY_AFTERTOUCH,
   CONTROL_CHANGE,
   PROGRAM_CHANGE,
   CHANNEL_AFTERTOUCH,
   PITCH_WHEEL_CHANGE,
   MIDIEVENTS_CNT,
};
constexpr bool operator==(const MidiEvents& a, const char& b) {
    return b == static_cast<char>(a);
}

struct MidiEventType {
    char value;
    char num_bytes; // Store the number of bytes required to be read
    constexpr bool operator==(const char& other) const {
        return value == other;        
    }
    constexpr bool operator==(const MidiEvents& other) const {
        return static_cast<char>(other) == value;
    }
};
constexpr bool operator==(const char& a, const MidiEventType& b) {
    return b == a;
}

struct MidiEventTypes {
    static constexpr std::array<
        MidiEventType, static_cast<size_t>(MidiEvents::MIDIEVENTS_CNT)
    > _data{{
        [static_cast<char>(MidiEvents::NOTE_OFF)] = {8, 2},
        [static_cast<char>(MidiEvents::NOTE_ON)] = {9, 2},
        /* etc.... */
    }};
    static constexpr auto get(char m) {
        for (auto&& i : _data) {
            if (i.value == m) {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
    static constexpr auto get(MidiEvents m) {
        return _data[static_cast<char>(m)];
    }
    static constexpr auto GetRequiredBytesByEventType(char m) {
        return get(m).num_bytes;
    }
    static constexpr auto GetRequiredBytesByEventType(MidiEvents m) {
        return get(m).num_bytes;
    }
    static constexpr auto NOTE_OFF = _data[static_cast<char>(MidiEvents::NOTE_OFF)];
    static constexpr auto NOTE_ON = _data[static_cast<char>(MidiEvents::NOTE_ON)];
};
```

Wiht that:

```
int main() {
    // Here's some pseudo code usage:
    constexpr char nTestValue = 8;
    if (nTestValue == MidiEventTypes::NOTE_OFF) {
        std::cout << "We now need to read " << MidiEventTypes::NOTE_OFF.num_bytes << " more bytes...." << std::endl;
    }
    // We should also be able to do something like this:
    // Get the number of read bytes required for a MIDI event with a type equal to the value of nTestValue.
    constexpr char nBytesNeeded = MidiEventTypes::get(nTestValue).num_bytes; 
    // Or alternatively:
    constexpr char nBytesNeeded2 = MidiEventTypes::GetRequiredBytesByEventType(nTestValue);
    // and:
    constexpr char nBytesNeeded3 = MidiEventTypes::GetRequiredBytesByEventType(MidiEvents::NOTE_OFF);
}
```

> it won't let me create a static unordered_map

Yes, `unordered_map` allocates memory and sorts stuff inside it. Just use a plain array, do not allocate memory anywhere - it's all known at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

I see two viable solutions:

1. If your data are highly inhomogeneous and hierarchical structure can be more layers deep, using JSON will work and provide plenty of flexibility, e.g. using [Niels Lohmann's C++ json library](https://github.com/nlohmann/json). You would lost some performance and type safety, but you are quite flexible in possibilities on how to structure your data and what types would be there.
2. If performance and type safety is more important you can use limited but much more performant code like e.g.:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

enum class Events { NOTE_OFF, PROGRAM_CHANGE };

const std::map<Events, const int> bytes_per_events = {
    {Events::NOTE_OFF, 2},
    {Events::PROGRAM_CHANGE, 1}
    // ...
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << bytes_per_events.at(Events::NOTE_OFF) << " "
              << bytes_per_events.at(Events::PROGRAM_CHANGE) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

You can use Classes instead of ints or employ different container, depending on what is required.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to my proposed solution using templates, here is a simpler one based on the answer by Jarod42. We'll use an array and take advantage of the fact that the keys are contiguous (8->14). When looking up for a key we'll just substract 8; that way the array can hold exactly 7 elements. This approach is simpler than the templates but can only be used when the values to look up for are contiguous. Live code [here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/52c387199f55f288)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

struct MidiEventType
{
    char value;
    char bytes;
    
    constexpr operator char() const { return value; }
};

struct MidiEventTypes
{
    static constexpr MidiEventType NOTE_OFF { 8, 2};
    static constexpr MidiEventType NOTE_ON { 9, 2};
    static constexpr MidiEventType KEY_AFTERTOUCH { 10, 2};
    static constexpr MidiEventType CONTROL_CHANGE { 11, 2};
    static constexpr MidiEventType PROGRAM_CHANGE  { 12, 1};
    static constexpr MidiEventType CHANNEL_AFTERTOUCH { 13, 1};
    static constexpr MidiEventType PITCH_WHEEL_CHANGE { 14, 2};
    
    static constexpr std::array<MidiEventType, 7> events{NOTE_OFF, NOTE_ON, KEY_AFTERTOUCH, CONTROL_CHANGE, PROGRAM_CHANGE, CHANNEL_AFTERTOUCH, PITCH_WHEEL_CHANGE};
    
    static constexpr auto get(char key)
    {
        // offset the key by 8 and then look into the array
        return events[(std::size_t)key - 8];
    }
};

int main()
{
    MidiEventTypes::get(MidiEventTypes::CONTROL_CHANGE).bytes;
    MidiEventTypes::get(MidiEventTypes::PROGRAM_CHANGE).bytes;
}
```

Comment: I'd considered doing the `-8` thing, but avoided it for two reasons: it seems like a "magic number" that may be somewhat confusing to another programmer (meaning me, six months from now) and it only works in this specific case, whereas I'm trying to find a more generic answer that can be applied any time this type of structure is required (ie not just for MIDI events). I think your template answer is better, so I voted for that one. :)