# When using variadric template, how to get nth arguments type?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates

I want to have a class that holds `n` values, much like `std::tuple`. I can't quite use tuple though, as there is additional logic in obtaining the values - they are on demand.

Please consider this class I wrote as an example:

```
// somewhere else
template<typename TVal>
TVal valueGetter() { ... };

template<typename ...TColValue>
class ResultRow
{
public:
  template<unsigned int TIndex>
  get_nth_from_variadric<TIndex, TColValue> GetValue() const
  {
    return valueGetter<get_nth_from_variadric<TIndex, TColValue> >();
  }
  

};
```

What I want it to work like is that the user simply calls `int myVal = GetValue<1>`, given class template params `ResultRow<bool, int>`. For this to work, I need to be able to convert the index of the template argument into type.

How can I do that?

Comment: Have a look at [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47442393/8658157). It uses multi-inheritance which is actually really fast.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I've understood it correctly, but perhaps you could instead use a `std::tuple` of value getter functors to make the actual _obtaining values on demand_ working?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I am not entirely sure what would that like - to populate the functor types in the tuple, I'd need to know the types they should return, and I'm back where I started.

Comment: @TomášZato-ReinstateMonica Hmm, ok, yeah.

Comment: *"I can't quite use tuple though"*. Don't understand the reason, `std::get<I>(tuple)` is C++11, `std::get<T>(tuple)` is C++14. And it seems I am not alone, as 3/4 of the answers use `std::tuple`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Well, I didn't know it could be used the way many answers have demonstrated.

Comment: @Elliott What is missing from the example? `TVal valueGetter()` in my case will be a method that fetches NTH column from a database query result row.

Comment: @TomášZato-ReinstateMonica, well, what's `NoCopy`? Also, `I didn't know it could be used the way many answers have demonstrated`, well I provided godbolt links to demonstrate that, and also to explain why recursive inheritance (used in the accepted answer) is a bad idea - if you don't care about speed you should just wrap a `tuple`.

Comment: @Elliott I'm sorry, I honestly didn't consider performance when accepting the answer, I don't really yet understand the matter at hand. I will review this. And yes, you provided links to demonstrate how to use the tuple, but that was after I asked the question - I was only explaining that when I asked the question, I didn't know how to use tuple for this, or even that you can.

Comment: @TomášZato-ReinstateMonica: Risk with such false-requirement is that you can have missing answers and possibly just *"suboptimal"* answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the type from parameter pack with the help of a recursive inheriting type trait.

```
template<unsigned int TIndex, typename ...TColValue>
struct get_nth_from_variadric_type;

template<unsigned int TIndex, typename Head, typename... Tail >
struct get_nth_from_variadric_type<TIndex, Head, Tail...>
    : get_nth_from_variadric_type<TIndex-1, Tail...> { };

template<typename Head, typename... Tail>
struct get_nth_from_variadric_type<0, Head, Tail...> {
   using type = Head;
};

template<unsigned int TIndex, typename ...TColValue>
using get_nth_from_variadric = typename get_nth_from_variadric_type<TIndex, TColValue...>::type;
```

Then use it like

```
template<typename ...TColValue>
class ResultRow
{
public:
  template<unsigned int TIndex>
  get_nth_from_variadric<TIndex, TColValue...> GetValue() const
  {
    return valueGetter<get_nth_from_variadric<TIndex, TColValue...> >();
  }
};
```

Answer (score 5):

One approach would be to forward the variadic arguments into a tuple and then use [`std::get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get), for example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

template<size_t N, typename... Args>
auto f(Args&&... args)
{
  return std::get<N>(std::tuple{std::forward<Args>(args)...});
}

int main(void)
{
  std::cout << f<0>("Hello", "world") << ' ' << f<1>("Hello", "world") << f<0>('!') << '\n';
}
```

Comment: [`std::forward_as_tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/forward_as_tuple) may also be useful in the more generic scenario.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that we ***should*** wrap stl's `tuple_element`, but you could:

```
template <std::size_t, class>
struct nth_of_pack;

template <std::size_t N, template <class...> class Pack, class ... Ts>
struct nth_of_pack <N, Pack<Ts...>>
    : std::tuple_element<N, std::tuple<Ts...>> {};

template <std::size_t N, class Pack>
using nth_of_pack_t = typename nth_of_pack<N, Pack>::type;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/nn5Tdxcf6)

---

### Better solution:

`tuple_element` seems to always be implemented with recursive inheritance which is extremely slow (I've tested on MSVC, gcc, clang with many of their versions - I still don't know why they use recursion!). It also doesn't work with anything other than `tuple`, which is unfortunate. So instead we'll make something generic for any class with type arguments (which I call a "pack").

Below we extrapolate **Julius**'s [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47442393/8658157) for this specific problem. See their answer for discussion on performance regarding standard inheritance, multi-inheritance, and `tuple_element`. Here we use multi-inheritance:

```
#include <utility>

template <class T>
struct tag
{
    using type = T;
};

template <class T>
using result_t = typename T::type;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

template<std::size_t, std::size_t, class>
struct type_if_equal {};

template<std::size_t n, class T>
struct type_if_equal<n, n, T> : tag<T> {};

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

template<std::size_t n, class Is, class... Ts>
struct select_nth_implementation;

template<std::size_t n, std::size_t... is, class... Ts>
struct select_nth_implementation<n, std::index_sequence<is...>, Ts...>
    : type_if_equal<n, is, Ts>... {};

template<std::size_t n, class... Ts>
struct select_nth : select_nth_implementation<
    n, std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>, Ts...> {};

template<std::size_t n, class... Ts>
using select_nth_t = result_t<select_nth<n, Ts...>>;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

template <std::size_t, class>
struct nth_of_pack;

template <std::size_t N, template <class...> class Pack, class ... Ts>
struct nth_of_pack <N, Pack<Ts...>> : select_nth<N, Ts...> {};

template <std::size_t N, class Pack>
using nth_of_pack_t = result_t<nth_of_pack<N, Pack>>;
```

We can then use like so:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class...>
class foo;

int main () {
    using my_tuple = foo<int, bool, char, double>;
    using second_type = nth_of_pack_t<2, my_tuple>;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<second_type, char>);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/c6or6z3cx)