# C++20 How to get the last element of a parameter pack of std::size_t

Tags: c++, c++20, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I've seen many answers online such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54130256/4048657), but they do not seem to work when the parameter pack is of `std::size_t`.

```
template <typename ...Ts>
struct select_last
{
    using type = typename decltype((std::type_identity<Ts>{}, ...))::type;
};

template<std::size_t... N>
class Example {
private:
    using type = select_last<int, double>::type; // works
    using size_t_type = select_last<size_t... N>::type; // doesn't work
};
```

How can I get the last element of a parameter pack of type `std::size_t`?

Comment: The type-based code doesn't work if any of those `Ts` cannot be default constructed. You should use `std::declval<Ts>()` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `template<std::size_t... N>` is based on a non-type template parameter, so you cannot extract *the type* (or more precisely, there is no sense in trying to extract the type - I can just tell you it is `std::size_t`!), you may however extract *the value*, into a static constexpr.

Here is the proposed code:

```
template<std::size_t... N>
struct Last {
    static constexpr std::size_t val = (N, ...); // take the last
};

int main() {
    std::cout << Last<1, 2, 3, 99>::val; // 99
}
```

If you want, you can actually have it work for any type:

```
template<auto... N>
struct Last {
    static constexpr auto val = (N, ...); // take the last
};
```

Comment: added, see: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ec797227fc5ee382

Comment: I would use something like `constexpr std::array<size_t, sizeof...(N)> vals{N...}`. It basically gives you the full control over the pack.