# Type trait that returns the template parameter of a template function

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, type-traits

Suppose one has the following template function:

```
template<typename T>  auto foobar ()  { return std::string("why not"); }
```

**Question:** is it possible to define a type trait that provides the template parameter of the function ?

If we call `get_template_parameter` such a trait, one could then write:

```
template<typename T>  auto foobar ()  { return std::string("why not"); }

using type = typename get_template_parameter <decltype(foobar<double>)>::type;

static_assert (std::is_same_v<type,double>);
```

**UPDATE:** I added a dummy result to the `foobar` function in order to underline the fact that the template parameter is not related to the result of the function.

Comment: Why is this empty-body function returning `auto`?

Comment: I am afraid you can't since `T` is lost when a function template is instantiated. You have no way to retrieve it from its signature, it's just a normal function. You could wrap it into a callable class template, but that may be ugly.

Comment: why do you need this type? Is it for logging or to make some usage of this function template instantion argument type?

Comment: From **inside** the function, some (`constexpr`) black magic can be done with `std::source_location::function_name()`/`__FUNC__` to retrieve `"T = double"` (as string)...

Comment: @edrezen: As "PiotrNycz" requested, you need to better clarify what your purpose is. Your function as shown doesn't utilize "T" so why are you doing this? If "T" is being used inside the function as you mentioned in response to "David G", then show how. Moreover, do you actually need to get hold of "T" outside the function as you've shown. It's not clear what you're actual requirements are.

Comment: @Larry: actually, the prototype of ```foobar``` is defined by end users so I can't really change it. However, I need to execute ```foobar``` in different contexts (specific hw architectures) where the incoming arguments types need sometime to be modified. A solution is to ask end users to make ```foobar``` a  template function, thus without modifying the prototype itself; then I could use the template parameter to analyze/adapt at compilation time the arguments types. But from the different remarks, I guess it's not possible as such.

Comment: @edrezen Well, I still don't understand what the endgame is. It's very vague and (TBH) confusing. I still don't know what "T" is for and it also sounds like "foobar" itself can potentially have different argument types. Are you're simply trying to figure out an (arbitrary) function's argument types at compile time and even modify them (based on your description)? If so then my traits class [here](https://github.com/HexadigmAdmin/FunctionTraits) is something you may want to check out. Otherwise you need to clarify things better (maybe more than you can do in a comment).

Comment: @Larry: "simply trying to figure out an (arbitrary) function's argument types at compile time and even modify them (based on your description)" -> yes, this could be described like this. Thanks for the link, I will definitely have a look.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing write your functions as functors you can extract the template type as follows:

```
template<typename T>
struct foobar {
    auto operator()() const { return std::string("why not"); }
};

template<typename T>
struct get_template_parameter;

// specialization for functor with single template parameter
template<template<typename> class Functor, typename T>
struct get_template_parameter<Functor<T>>
{
    using type = T;
};

int main() {
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<double, get_template_parameter<foobar<double>>::type>);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An other option, less intrusive than making the function a functor or returning a pair, would be to add the templated type `T` as the last argument of the function with a default argument, allowing the function to be called with the same signature than before.

Then the type can be determined, by looking at `decltype(foobar<double>)` and extracting the last argument as presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46560993/23361122).

```
template<typename T>
struct tag
{
    using type = T;
};

template<typename... Ts>
struct select_last
{
    // Use a fold-expression to fold the comma operator over the parameter pack.
    using type = typename decltype((tag<Ts>{}, ...))::type;
};

template<typename T>
struct get_template_parameter;

template<typename R, typename... T>
struct get_template_parameter<R(T...)> : select_last<T...> {
};

template<typename T>
using get_template_parameter_t = typename get_template_parameter<T>::type;

template <typename T>
auto foobar([[maybe_unused]] T t = {}) {
    return std::string();
}


int main() {
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<double, get_template_parameter_t<decltype(foobar<double>)>>);
}
```

Note that this can be problematic, if `T` is somehow not easy to construct. Then an option would be to make the last argument a reference of `T` and letting the `tag` remove the reference again:

```
template<typename T>
struct tag
{
    using type = std::remove_reference_t<T>;
};

/* code as before ... */

template <typename T>
auto func([[maybe_unused]] T& t = {}) {
    return std::string();
}
```

Comment: thank you for this answer. I found something quite similar in case there is no possibility to answer the original question without modifying the prototype of the function. The little difference with your answer is that one just needs to write ```template <typename T> auto func([[maybe_unused]] T = {})```

Comment: I mean you don't even need to have a name for the argument, which should underlines the fact that we need only the type ```T```.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all you need is:

```
template<typename T> T foobar();

using type = decltype(foobar<double>());

static_assert(std::is_same_v<type, double>);
```

Comment: Actually, the template type ```T``` can be used inside the body of ```foobar``` but it is not necessarily the return type of the function ```foobar```.

Comment: @edrezen -- yes, but that's not what the question asked.

Comment: Ok, I put an example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/fv19YeP4K)  with a returned type different to the provided template.

Comment: @edrezen -- you're right again. The question asked `auto foobar() {}`, which doesn't compile. The answer changed that.

Comment: @edrezen I'm afraid it's not possible to get the type then, since `T` is not related to the signature of the function.

Comment: @David G -- Yes, that's what I feared... Actually, I guess it would be possible if we allow to provide the template type ```T``` as part of the result, for instance as a ```std::pair<std::string,T>``` in the example. But I was looking for a solution where the body of the function had not to be modified.