# why sizeof...(T) so slow? implement C++14 make_index_sequence without sizeof...(T)

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I found implement of C++14 make_index_sequence  'algorithm':

```
template< int ... > struct index_sequence{   using type = index_sequence; };

template< typename T> using invoke = typename T :: type ;

template< typename T, typename U > struct concate;
template< int ...i, int ... j>
struct concate< index_sequence<i...>, index_sequence<j...> >
        : index_sequence< i... ,  (j + sizeof ... (i ) )... > {};
  //                                   \          /
  //                                    ----------
 //                                   I think here is slowly.
template< int n>
struct make_index_sequence_help : concate< 
                          invoke< make_index_sequence_help<n/2>>,
                          invoke< make_index_sequence_help<n-n/2>>
                          > {};

template<> struct make_index_sequence_help <0> : index_sequence<>{};
template<> struct make_index_sequence_help <1> : index_sequence<0>{};

template< int n> using make_index_sequence = invoke< make_index_sequence_help<n> >;


int main()
{
    using iseq = make_index_sequence< 1024 > ; // successfull
    using jseq = make_index_sequence< 1024 * 16 > ; // a lot of compile time!!!
    using kseq = make_index_sequence< 1024 * 64 > ; // can't compile: memory exhauted!!!
};
```

---

But, when I replace sizeof...(i) to  concrete number from 'concate',  then make_index_sequence< 1024 *64>   -compiled very fast.

```
template< int s, typename T, typename U > struct concate;
template< int s, int ...i, int ...j >
struct concate< s, index_sequence<i...>, index_sequence<j...> >
 :  index_sequence< i..., ( j + s ) ... > {};

// and 
template< int n >
struct make_index_sequence_help : concate<
                                  n / 2 , 
                          invoke< make_index_sequence_help< n / 2 > >,
                          invoke< make_index_sequence_help< n - n/2 > >
                           >{};
```

**Q: Why sizeof ... (i )  so slow ?**

I test with gcc 4.8.1 
Update:

For first case:  ( only  1024  and 1024*16 ).

```
g++  -Wall  -c "ctx_fptr.cpp"   -g  -O2 -std=c++11 -ftime-report
Execution times (seconds)
 garbage collection    :   0.06 ( 1%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.06 ( 0%) wall       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 preprocessing         :   0.03 ( 0%) usr   0.04 ( 2%) sys   0.09 ( 1%) wall     293 kB ( 0%) ggc
 parser                :  10.41 (97%) usr   1.61 (95%) sys  12.01 (96%) wall 2829842 kB (99%) ggc
 name lookup           :   0.12 ( 1%) usr   0.04 ( 2%) sys   0.23 ( 2%) wall    7236 kB ( 0%) ggc
 dead store elim1      :   0.01 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.00 ( 0%) wall       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 symout                :   0.15 ( 1%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.15 ( 1%) wall   12891 kB ( 0%) ggc
 unaccounted todo      :   0.00 ( 0%) usr   0.01 ( 1%) sys   0.00 ( 0%) wall       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 TOTAL                 :  10.78             1.70            12.55            2850835 kB
```

For second case: ( all 1024, 1024*16 and 1024 * 64 )

```
g++  -Wall  -c "ctx_fptr.cpp"   -g  -O2 -std=c++11 -ftime-report 
Execution times (seconds)
 preprocessing         :   0.02 ( 2%) usr   0.01 ( 5%) sys   0.05 ( 4%) wall     293 kB ( 0%) ggc
 parser                :   0.54 (45%) usr   0.10 (53%) sys   0.71 (50%) wall   95339 kB (58%) ggc
 name lookup           :   0.47 (39%) usr   0.04 (21%) sys   0.47 (33%) wall   20197 kB (12%) ggc
 tree PRE              :   0.01 ( 1%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.00 ( 0%) wall       1 kB ( 0%) ggc
 varconst              :   0.00 ( 0%) usr   0.01 ( 5%) sys   0.00 ( 0%) wall      17 kB ( 0%) ggc
 symout                :   0.17 (14%) usr   0.03 (16%) sys   0.18 (13%) wall   47092 kB (29%) ggc
 TOTAL                 :   1.21             0.19             1.41             163493 kB
```

Comment: template expansion and processing is "interpreted" inside the GCC compiler and is slow at *compile time* (not at runtime of the compiled code). The compiler needs to generate big ASTs (with a lot of meta-data, e.g. precise source location)

Comment: Q. Where's your evidence? What makes you think it is sizeof, of all things? It's just a symbol table lookup at compile time.

Comment: You may test with online compiler. http://ideone.com/TLuDiA.  I ASK ABOUT COMPILE-TIME, not a RUNTIME.

Comment: But testing the compilation time does not proves that `sizeof...` (specifically!) is slow at compile time.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch. test please, with -ftime-report options, time difference between first and second implementations is very big.

Comment: So what? Template expansion is known to be expansive at compile time in some weird cases. I suggest you to use some `-fdump-*` flags of GCC to understand what *intermediate internal representations* are involved!

Comment: @KhurshidNormuradov It's probably not `sizeof...` itself, but the pseudo-nested expansion. But this is all very speculative, your analysis needs to be much deeper if you want to understand what is the root cause for the difference. `sizeof...` here might trigger something, but there might be other ways to trigger or avoid the slow compile times.

Comment: clang works well with -O3 with both cases, but gcc is really to slow, 0.16 with constant and 7.58 with sizeof... on template instantiation.

Comment: It is the commonly observed pattern: `clang` compiles faster that `g++` but GCC produces slightly faster code (at runtime) that Clang.

Comment: @KhurshidNormuradov: Report this as a bug to [GCC bugzilla](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/).

Comment: @wilx. Added http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58999

Comment: @Basile, this is orders of magnitude slower, so is definitely a performance bug (I've confirmed the bugzilla report)

Answer (score 3):

The compilation is slow and uses a lot of memory because you are recursively expanding templates. This is being done at compile time, it creates a large number of types, and this can use a lot of memory. It is not caused by sizeof or any other individual statement. It is the recursion that causes every bit of the template expansion to be expensive.

I've hit this exact same problem with VC++ -- I found that my compiles would get arbitrarily slow as I passed in larger constants to a template function that I wrote.

Of course, in my case I was *trying* to make the compiler run slowly. But still, maybe this will be helpful:

https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2014/03/10/making-compiles-slow/