# Generating template specializations through template metaprogramming. Odd compiler behaviour

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-meta-programming

#### Source code

This is basically a non-recursive `std::tuple_element` implementation.

**Note:** To make this non-recursive, you must replace `std::make_index_sequence` with a non-recursive implementation. I left it with `std::make_index_sequence` in order to provide a MVCE.

`deduct<std::size_t, T>` has a specialization of `deduct_impl<T>` that is generated from the index sequence template argument it receives. It is used in order to deduce the type at `index` in a variadic type template or tuple.

`itp<std::size_t>` and `itp<std::size_t, T>` is an index-type-pair used to expand the variadic indices template with a type variadic template in order to match the generated specialization.

`deducer<std::size_t, T...>` puts it all together by specializing `deduct<std::size_t, T>` and `deduct_impl<T>` by using `std::conditional_t` to generate the correct specialization.

Basically, for `std::tuple<void, int, char>`, in order to get the type at index 1, it creates `itp_base<0>, itp<1, int>, itp_base<2>` and passes it to `deduct` and `deduct_impl`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>

template <std::size_t index>
struct itp_base {};

template <std::size_t index, typename T>
struct itp : itp_base<index> {};

template <std::size_t index, typename IndexSequence>
struct deduct;

template <std::size_t index, std::size_t... indices>
struct deduct<index, std::index_sequence<indices...>>
{
    template <typename Tuple>
    struct deduct_impl;

    template <typename T, typename... R>
    struct deduct_impl<std::tuple<itp_base<indices>..., itp<index, T>, R...>>
    {
        using type = T;
    };
};

template <std::size_t index, typename... Types>
class deducer
{
private:
    static_assert( index < sizeof...( Types ), "deducer::index out of bounds" );

    template <typename IndexSequence>
    struct deducer_impl;

    template <std::size_t... indices>
    struct deducer_impl<std::index_sequence<indices...>>
    {
        using type = typename deduct<index, std::make_index_sequence<index>
        >::template deduct_impl
        <
            std::tuple
            <
                std::conditional_t
                <
                    std::is_base_of<itp_base<indices>, itp<index, Types>>::value,
                    itp<index, Types>,
                    itp_base<indices>
                >...
            >
        >::type;
    };

public:
    using type = typename deducer_impl<
        std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...( Types )>>::type;
};

template <std::size_t index, typename... Types>
using tuple_element_t = typename deducer<index, Types...>::type;

int main()
{
    tuple_element_t<3, int, void, char, std::string> s{ "string" };
    std::cout << s << '\n';
}
```

#### Odd compiler behaviour

**Clang++**

I'm getting warnings for non-deducible template arguments from Clang++, but the program outputs correctly.

**Visual C++ v140**

The type is detected correctly. However I get the following warning:

`warning C4552: '<<': operator has no effect; expected operator with side-effect`

The program does not output anything.

**G++**

Everything works properly.

#### Demo

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7cb3ac06ab4b2d4c

Comment: @dyp The code is actually detecting the correct type properly in all three compilers, so if it was miswritten, wouldn't it just fail? Either way, there's no deduction actually going on there, because `indices` has already been deduced and is just being expanded.

Comment: Right, I got confused.

Comment: Side remark: I remember Kurshid having a simpler solution for the `conditional_t` / `is_base_of` part. As far as I can see, it can also be applied here: something like `tuple<itp<indices == index, Types>...>` where `itp` is a `template<bool, typename> struct itp;`

Comment: I think clang emits a false positive warning; MSVC's behaviour seems to be broken. For example, replace your main with a `static_assert( is_same<tuple_element_t<..>, std::string>::value, "" );` and it complains about this not being a constant expression.

Comment: @dyp Can you link me to that please? I actually came up with this solution after looking at your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18594309/2296177 The reason being that I was getting compiler errors about template depth. I know that your solution definitely works on G++ as well.

Comment: Link to what? Kurshid's solution is just below my answer, and I mentioned in a comment to Kurshid's answer that you could replace the `xor` with an `==`.

Comment: Oh, and if you need a really efficient version, please take a look at boost.hana and its implementors blog: http://ldionne.com/2015/11/29/efficient-parameter-pack-indexing/

Comment: @dyp Sorry, I completely missed his answer. Thanks for that boost.hana link.

Comment: It seems a false positive warning. example can be simplified btw [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9dee59ac5df0d815)