# Why does libstdc++ store std::tuple elements in reverse order?

Tags: c++, c++11, libstdc++, libc++

According to [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150213003511/http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/2012/07/06/optimal-tuple-i.html), with regards to std::tuple...

> libstdc++ always places the members in reverse order, and libc++ always places the members in the order given

Assuming that's true, is there a reason (historical or otherwise) why libstdc++ uses reverse order?

Bonus: Has either implementation ever changed its std::tuple ordering for any reason?

Comment: I'm not aware of either library breaking its ABI, and reversing that order would absolutely break the ABI.

Comment: It hadn't even occurred to me that changing the order would break the ABI, but now it seems obvious. I guess that answers that part of the question. Thanks.

Comment: I made a change to the libstdc++ `tuple` layout yesterday (see [PR 56785](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56785)) but only to remove some empty base classes and make it more compact. The ordering of elements didn't change.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9643480/576911) for why libc++ chose forward order.  As for why libstdc++ chose reverse order, that is probably because that's how it was demonstrated in the variadics template proposal, and is the more obvious implementation.

Bonus:  No.  These orderings have been stable in both libraries.

**Update**

libc++ chose forward storage order because:

1. It is implementable.
2. The implementation has good compile-time performance.
3. It gives clients of libc++ something that is intuitive and controllable, should they care about the order of the storage, and are willing to depend on it while using libc++, despite its being unspecified.

In short, the implementor of the libc++ `tuple` merely felt that storing the objects in the order the client (implicitly) specified was the quality thing to do.

Comment: Maybe it's because I don't grok TMP at all, but I don't see where the linked post says why libc++ chose forward order. It explains why a non-recursive tuple implementation is good (which makes sense to me in principle, though I find the linked libc++ code for it totally unreadable) and then mentions at the end that libc++ uses forward order without any explanation. Is there meant to be an implication that forward order is the "obvious implementation" of a non-recursive tuple?