# Why use std::make_unique in C++17?

Tags: c++, c++17, unique-ptr

As far as I understand, C++14 introduced `std::make_unique` because, as a result of the parameter evaluation order not being specified, this was unsafe:

```
f(std::unique_ptr<MyClass>(new MyClass(param)), g()); // Syntax A
```

(Explanation: if the evaluation first allocates the memory for the raw pointer, then calls `g()` and an exception is thrown before the `std::unique_ptr` construction, then the memory is leaked.)

Calling `std::make_unique` was a way to constrain the call order, thus making things safe:

```
f(std::make_unique<MyClass>(param), g());             // Syntax B
```

---

Since then, C++17 has clarified the evaluation order, making Syntax A safe too, so here's my question: **is there still a reason to use `std::make_unique` over `std::unique_ptr`'s constructor in C++17? Can you give some examples?**

As of now, the only reason I can imagine is that it allows to type `MyClass` only once (assuming you don't need to rely on polymorphism with `std::unique_ptr<Base>(new Derived(param))`). However, that seems like a pretty weak reason, especially when `std::make_unique` doesn't allow to specify a deleter while `std::unique_ptr`'s constructor does.

And just to be clear, I'm not advocating in favor of removing `std::make_unique` from the Standard Library (keeping it makes sense at least for backward compatibility), but rather wondering if there are still situations in which it is strongly preferred to `std::unique_ptr`

Comment: *However, that seems like a pretty weak reason* --> Why it's a weak reason? It effectively reduces code duplication of type. As for the deleter, how often you are using a custom deleter when you use `std::unique_ptr`? It's not a argument to against `make_unique`

Comment: I say it's a weak reason because if there was no `std::make_unique` in the first place, I don't think that would be reason enough to add it to the STL, especially when it's a syntax which is less expressive than using the constructor, not more

Comment: If you have a program, created in c++14, using make_unique, you do not want the function to get removed from stl. Or if you want it to be backwards compatible.

Comment: @Serge That's a good point, but it's a bit besides the object of my question. I'll make an edit to make it clearer

Comment: @Eternal please stop refering to C++ Standard Library as STL as it is incorrect and creates confusion. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205491/whats-the-difference-between-stl-and-c-standard-library

Comment: I wasn't aware of that. Thanks

Comment: I just wish we could write `std::unique_ptr::make(param)` instead of needing a `make_XXXX` freestanding function because of language restrictions.

Comment: @einpoklum Having a `std::unique_ptr::make(param)` would actually mean less encapsulation, because the function would have access to the private members of the class. It's not like the `make_XXXX` functions are global functions either: they're in the namespace `std` and are included from headers that make sense. See this for more info on members vs freestanding functions: http://gotw.ca/publications/mill02.htm

Comment: @Eternal: 1. I didn't argue for it because of encapsulation. 2. Since the class author would write it, I don't see why such access would be a problem. 3. Indeed, I should have said `std::make_XXXX` rather than `make_XXXX`, I didn't mean to suggest it's a global function.

Comment: @einpoklum I didn't mean you argued about encapsulation or global function. Sorry I didn't express myself clearly. I was basically trying to say that having a freestanding function in this context is considered a better practice than having a member function. See http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197 for more details

Comment: Well, C++17 has not actually *clarified* the evaluation order (there was nothing *unclear* about it before), though it has *constrained* it (not all that was legal is still allowed).

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You're right that the main reason was removed. There are still the *don't use new* guidelines and that it is less typing reasons (don't have to repeat the type or use the word `new`). Admittedly those aren't strong arguments but I really like not seeing `new` in my code.

Also don't forget about consistency. You absolutely should be using `make_shared` so using `make_unique` is natural and fits the pattern. It's then trivial to change `std::make_unique<MyClass>(param)` to `std::make_shared<MyClass>(param)` (or the reverse) where the syntax A requires much more of a rewrite.

Comment: @reggaeguitar If I see a `new` I need to stop and think: how long is this pointer going to live?  Did I handle it correctly?  If there is an exception, is everything cleaned up correctly?  I'd like to not ask myself those questions and waste my time on it and if I don't use `new`, I don't have to ask those questions.

Comment: Imagine you do a grep over all the source files of your project and don't find a single `new`. Wouldn't this be wonderful?

Comment: The main advantage of the "don't use new" guideline it that it's simple, so it's an easy guideline to give to the less experienced developers you may be working with. I hadn't realized at first, but that has value in and of itself

Comment: @NathanOliver You actually don't _absolutely_ have to be using `std::make_shared` - imagine a case where the allocated object is big and there are a lot of `std::weak_ptr`-s pointing to it: it would be better to let the object be deleted as soon as the last shared pointer is destroyed and live with just a small shared area.

Comment: @DevNull How would you get into that case without creating a `weak_ptr` from a `shared_ptr` in the first place?

Comment: @NathanOliver you wouldn't. What I'm talking about is the disadvantage of `std::make_shared` https://stackoverflow.com/a/20895705/8414561 where the memory that was used to store the object can't be freed until the last `std::weak_ptr` is gone (even if all `std::shared_ptr`-s pointing to it (and consequently the object itself) have been already destroyed).

Answer (score 64):

`make_unique` distinguishes `T` from `T[]` and `T[N]`, `unique_ptr(new ...)` does not.

You can easily get undefined behaviour by passing a pointer that was `new[]`ed to a `unique_ptr<T>`, or by passing a pointer that was `new`ed to a `unique_ptr<T[]>`.

Comment: It's worse: It not only does not, it's flat-out unable to.

Answer (score 23):

The reason is to have shorter code without duplicates. Compare

```
f(std::unique_ptr<MyClass>(new MyClass(param)), g());
f(std::make_unique<MyClass>(param), g());
```

You save `MyClass`, `new` and braces. It costs only one character more in *make* in comparison with *ptr*.

Comment: Well, as I said in the question, I can see it's less typing with only one mention of `MyClass`, but I was wondering if there was a stronger reason to use it

Comment: In many cases deduction guide would help to eliminate the `<MyClass>` part in the first variant.

Comment: It's already been said in the comments for other answers, but while c++17 introduced template type deduction for constructors, in the case of `std::unique_ptr` it's disallowed. It has to do with distinguishing `std::unique_ptr<T>` and `std::unique_ptr<T[]>`

Answer (score 19):

Every use of `new` has to be extra carefully audited for lifetime correctness; does it get deleted?  Only once?

Every use of `make_unique` doesn't for those extra characteristics; so long as the owning object has "correct" lifetime, it recursively makes the unique pointer have "correct".

Now, it is true that `unique_ptr<Foo>(new Foo())` is identical in all ways<sup>1</sup> to `make_unique<Foo>()`; it just requires a simpler "grep your source code for all uses of `new` to audit them".

---

<sup>1</sup> actually a lie in the general case.  Perfect forwarding isn't perfect, `{}`, default init, arrays are all exceptions.

Comment: Technically `unique_ptr<Foo>(new Foo)` isn't _quite_ identical to `make_unique<Foo>()`... the latter does `new Foo()` But otherwise, yes.

Comment: @barry true, overloaded operator new is possible.

Comment: @dedup what foul C++17 witchcraft is that?

Comment: @Deduplicator while c++17 introduced template type deduction for constructors, in the case of `std::unique_ptr` it's disallowed. If has to do with distinguishing `std::unique_ptr<T>` and `std::unique_ptr<T[]>`

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I didn't mean overloading new, I just meant default-init vs value-init.

Comment: @barry yes, I double checked, and apparently make unique calls new.  I think I covered the exceptions in my footnote now.

Answer (score 2):

> Since then, C++17 has clarified the evaluation order, making Syntax A safe too

That's really not good enough. Relying on a recently-introduced technical clause as the guarantee of safety is not a very robust practice:

- Someone might compile this code in C++14.
- You would be encouraging the use of raw `new`'s elsewhere, e.g. by copy-pasting your example.
- As S.M. suggests, since there's code duplication, one type might get changed without the other one being changed.
- Some kind of automatic IDE refactoring might move that `new` elsewhere (ok, granted, not much chance of that).

Generally, it's a good idea for your code to be appropriate/robust/clearly valid *without* resorting to language-laywering, looking up minor or obscure technical clauses in the standard.

(this is essentially the same argument I made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39068744/1593077) about the order of tuple destruction.)

Answer (score -2):

Consider
void function(std::unique_ptr(new A()), std::unique_ptr(new B())) { ... }

Suppose that new A() succeeds, but new B() throws an exception: you catch it to resume the normal execution of your program. Unfortunately, the C++ standard does not require that object A gets destroyed and its memory deallocated: memory silently leaks and there's no way to clean it up. By wrapping A and B into std::make_uniques you are sure the leak will not occur:

void function(std::make_unique(), std::make_unique()) { ... }
The point here is that std::make_unique and std::make_unique are now temporary objects, and cleanup of temporary objects is correctly specified in the C++ standard: their destructors will be triggered and the memory freed. So if you can, always prefer to allocate objects using std::make_unique and std::make_shared.

Comment: The author explicitly specified in question that in C++17 leaks shall not occur anymore. "Since then, C++17 has clarified the evaluation order, making Syntax A safe too, so here's my question: (...)". You did not answer his question.