# std::unique_ptr initialization methods

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers, undefined-behavior, unique-ptr

I see that `std::unique_ptr` has the following ways of initialization:

```
std::unique_ptr<some_class> sc_ptr{ new some_class };
```

wherein someone could `delete` the allocated `some_class` from underneath the `std::unique_ptr`.

and

```
some_class *scptr { new some_class }
std::unique_ptr<some_class> sc_ptr1{ scptr };
std::unique_ptr<some_class> sc_ptr2{ scptr };
```

Defeating the purpose of '*unique*' in the `std::unique_ptr` and also leading to UDB.

Now the question that I have is: Why does the `std::unique_ptr` class even allow above methods of initialization while it has the `std::make_unique<some_class>()` method at its disposal?

Am I missing something here?

Comment: How else would you construct a `unique_ptr` from a raw pointer? c++ provides you the tools to implement programs, if you choose to use those tools to shoot yourself in the foot the language won't prevent you from doing so

Comment: Also, it's partly for backwards compatibility.  `std::make_unique` was not available until C++14 so there will be a lot of programs out there that could make use of it but don't.

Comment: @AlanBirtles `std::make_unique` initializes using a raw pointer under the hood doesn't it?

Comment: @PaulSanders that was something I didn't know. Thanks!

Comment: @AbhishekAUdupa yes, unlike [`std::make_shared`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared), [`std::make_unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) is a simple wrapper around the constructor and has no performance benefit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several reasons:

1. `make_unique` takes custom deleter, so it is supposed to handle custom allocation. Passing allocator to a hypothetical `allocate_unique` is cumbersome.
2. The same as `.release()` can provide a junction with a code that manages lifetime differently (including API in C interface that use raw pointers).
3. Historical reasons, `make_unique` was only introduced in C++14.

Note also that starting C++17 the main reason to prefer `make_unique` over new was removed, so you may see `make_unique` only as a syntax sugar, not as exception safety utility. See [Why use std::make_unique in C++17?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53870522/why-use-stdmake-unique-in-c17/53871997)