# C++17 can the 'new' operator still leak memory?

Tags: c++, c++17, new-operator

I'm working on a project, and need a char buffer to send a struct over a network. I was using:

```
char* buf = new char[sizeof(obj)];
```

Later, someone told me that I would be leaking memory if I did it that way without deleting. I debugged my program with Visual Studio 2017 Professional, and my memory sat constant, no matter how many times I made this buffer.

My question is this: did C++17 fix the memory leak issues that the 'new' operator could cause, or is this something specific to the compiler I'm using? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You didn't leak memory, you leaked address space. If you wanna leak memory, try `for(;;) new char;`

Comment: And by the way this is not a bug, so there is no "fixing" involved.

Comment: @Joshua Never heard the term "leaked address space" before, what does it mean? Looks like a regular memory leak to me.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: If you allocate large chunks and don't write to it, the memory isn't actually allocated yet, only the address space is. Large chunks are allocated by memory mapping.

Comment: OP, are you thinking about [this obscure way of leaking memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53870522/2752075) that was fixed in C++17? C++17 didn't eliminate *all* memory leaks (how could it do that?), just one of the obscure sources of them.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat There is no difference between the two in C++ as far as I know. From what I understand, the difference may exist on platforms that do not commit memory until the first write. So until you try to access the object, that address is reserved but no memory for it is committed to your process yet. These platforms are incompatible with C++ but pretend otherwise.

Comment: @Joshua That is an implementation detail and is incompatible with C++. Some Linux installations work this way but they are non-conforment.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: It's an implementation detail that OP already observed.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I see. Heard something about it happening on Linux, but apparently Windows does it too. Was able to reproduce on MinGW.

Comment: @Joshua Windows does not have this behavior. Unless they are cross compiling, this is not what is happening. Edit : Can't speak for MinGW though... Edit 2 : I suspect it is more likely the method of verifying total memory usage is incorrect, that the array is actually cleaned up or even that the number of leaks observed has not been enough to require a new page.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat That may have been what I was thinking of, and confused it with normal memory leaks, thank you!

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Actually it has just enough of this behavior that the memory usage monitor in Windows reflects it. The memory is reserved out of the total but not yet allocated (this bit or operations engineer because of GB of CoW pages that weren't going to get written to still have to have enough swap to back them if they actually get copied, but memory usage doesn't show it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `new[]` without `delete[]` will indeed leak memory.  You might not see it unless you are leaking lots of buffers, depending on how your app's RTL allocates/caches memory under the hood.

Traditionally, using a `std::vector<char>`, or even a `std::string`, is the preferred choice for dynamic buffers, let them handle their own memory for you, eg:

```cpp
std::vector<char> buf(sizeof(obj));
or
std::string buf(sizeof(obj), 0);
```

If you absolutely need `new[]`/`delete[]` for some reason, consider using `std::unique_ptr<char[]>` instead, let it call `delete[]` for you, eg:

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<char[]> buf(new char[sizeof(obj)]);
or
auto buf = std::make_unique<char[]>(sizeof(obj));
```

Answer (score 2):

Yep, that looks like a memory leak.

If you don't want to explicitly call `delete` on dynamically allocated memory, the standard solution is to use a smart pointer, which generally uses "reference counting" in order to de-allocate the memory safely.

More info on smart pointers:  [What is a smart pointer and when should I use one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one)

As for why you didn't allocate more memory -- what are you measuring?  There are generally two "allocations" that happen:

1. Your memory allocator requests memory from the operating system.
2. Your memory allocator returns a pointer to some of that memory.

(Strictly speaking, this is not specific to your *compiler*, this is based on the implementation of `new`.  If you're using the standard Visual C++ toolchain, then in that sense, yeah, the implementation of `new` depends on Visual C++.  Here's a starting point:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/memory?view=vs-2019)

It's possible that you're measuring #1 -- how much memory is being allocated by the operating system.  For instance, `sizeof(obj)` may be 1 kilobyte, and your allocator may have requested 256K from the operating system.  So you have space to perform `new` and receive allocations within that memory buffer, without changing the OS-level memory footprint of your process.

As an experiment, I'd suggest allocating successively larger chunks of memory:

```
const int alloc_size = 4; // then 5, 6, 7...
for (int i = 0; i < (2<<alloc_size); i++) {
  // do your allocation here
}
```

and then finding out how many allocations you can perform before your measurement changes.