# Behaviour of delete[] (ptr, 0)

Tags: c++, pointers, delete-operator

Is the behaviour of this code defined?

```
int* ptr = new int[10];
operator delete[] (ptr, 0);
```

This code compiles fine and (on my machine) it seems nothing is happening. Is its the behaviour defined somewhere?

Comment: [This `operator delete` and `operator delete[]` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete) should be helpful. Exact which overload you're calling is hard to say though.

Comment: I think it's undefined behaviour. The comma operator evaluates `ptr` and discards the result, then passes `0` (an invalid address) to delete

Comment: @Tharwen It's a function call. There is no comma operator here.

Comment: @Tharwen 0 is a valid address to delete. It is a null pointer literal.

Comment: @Rakete1111 I see that now. How can it take 2 arguments though?

Comment: @eerorika I (mistakenly) thought deleting a null ptr was equivalent to deleting memory that hadn't been allocated with new and therefore undefined

Comment: @Tharwen They can have 3 arguments even! :) Have a look: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete

Answer (score 1):

#### tl;dr: The behavior might as well be undefined, avoid such a statement.

<sub>This answer is aimed at most C++ software developers, not so much at language-lawyer types who want the formal official answer.</sub>

The `delete[](ptr, 0)` call has no strong reason for the standard committee to define behavior for. Also, even if such a behavior were to be defined - there is no single obvious behavior we would expect:

- It could throw an exception.
- It could do nothing.
- It could be the same as `delete[](ptr)` or `delete[](ptr, 10)`.
- It could be even be 'defined' as implementation-defined...

It is not a good idea for your code to rely on such a choice, even if the standards committee had made it. It would make your code difficult to understand and easy to break - for somebody else, or even for yourself, a few years down the line.

That's why it doesn't really matter whether the behavior here is defined, and you should absolutely avoid such a statement.

See also :

- A rule-of-thumb for another such situation posited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39068744/1593077).
- C++ Core Guidelines [Rule R.11: Avoid calling `new` and `delete` explicitly](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rr-newdelete).

Answer (score 0):

In this statement

```
operator delete[] (ptr, 0);
```

there is called explicitly the deallocation function

```
void operator delete[](void*, std::size_t) noexcept;
```

The second parameter in the call that has the type `size_t` is just set to 0.

The behavior of the call then the second parameter is equal to 0 is undefined provided that when the allocated memory was not have the size equal to 0.

Comment: It's an operator call? It's not the comma operator but the arguments to the operator.

Comment: That would be `delete[](ptr, 0)` (without the `operator` keyword). Now the OP is calling the operator function directly.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow It's not better. There is no comma operator. `f(1, 2)` is not equivalent to `f(2)`. Here `f` is `operator delete[]`.

Comment: @Rakete1111 Og, you are right. I will delete the post.:)

Comment: Does it?  Cppreference states that it *Called instead of (1-2) if a user-defined replacement is provided*  and the OP has not mentioned overloading the operator.

Comment: Also the OP is asking if it is defined behavior.  Is it defined behavior to give it an incorrect size?