# Is this item from Effective Modern C++ still up to date?

Tags: c++, c++17, undefined-behavior, exception-safety

p.146 of effective modern C++ :

```
void processWidget(std::shared_ptr<Widget> spw, int priority);
void cusDel(Widget *ptr);//a custom deleter
```

This was an unsafe call prior to C++17 :

```
processWidget(std::shared_ptr<Wdiget>(new Widget, cusDel), computePriority());
```

It used to be unsafe because computePriority could be called after `new Widget` but before `std::share_ptr` constructor and if `computePriority` yielded an exception, the dynamically allcoated Widget would be leaked.
Therefore you could do this :

```
std::shared_ptr<Widget> spw(new Widget, cusDel);
processWidget(spw, computePriority());
```

Now this would add a copy constructor operation on shared_ptr. So you could also do this :

```
std::shared_ptr<Widget> spw(new Widget, cusDel);
processWidget(std::move(spw), computePriority());
```

So my question is, is the following code still able to leak memory in C++17?

```
processWidget(std::shared_ptr<Wdiget>(new Widget, cusDel), computePriority());
```

I've read [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points) but I'm still unsure, I believe that `std::shared_ptr<Wdiget>(new Widget, cusDel)` and `computePriority()` are both sequenced before the call to processWidget, however I think `computePriority()` can still throw an exception after `new` and before `shared_ptr` takes ownership of the newly created object.

Comment: Ok, I stand corrected. On a side note, my liking towards C++ has not grown a bit today.

Comment: @tevemadar I'm sorry to hear that. I'm hopeful that you only feel that way about *some* c++ programmers. The language is actually pretty cool :)

Comment: @cigien I did not say anything about programmers using C++, but that example with `int y = operator<<(S(j=1), j=2);`. There almost seems to be some actual proudness about the indeterminism of `j` at the end despite the mathematical meaning of parentheses, and perhaps common sense too. It's a bit like the `8/2(2+2)` meme, just it got real.

Comment: @tevemadar I'm not sure it's pride, it's just a recognition of the guarantees as provided by the language.

Comment: @cigien following your comment I just came back, and then re-read the thing. I was commenting on the wrong part here. I didn't care about the indeterminism of `j`, that's just an evaluation order, which argument (of `operator<<()`) comes first, I can live with that being "random". I care about the "random" sequencing of `S()`. Should `j` be a global variable, this indeterminately sequenced nature could mean that `S()` gets `1` as its argument, but sees `j=2` for the variable. Actually that's what I don't like.

Comment: @tevemadar Agreed, and that's what is fixed in c++17. Now `S()` is guaranteed to see `j=1`.

Comment: @cigien: Does the Standard mandate everything an implementation would need to do to be suitable for every purpose, for some particular purposes, or for no particular purpose?  If only for some purposes, what purposes are those?  Since C++ was used for 14 years before the first standard was published, I don't think it would be fair to equate the Standard with "the language" unless the Standard includes everything needed to make implementations suitable for all the purposes that were accomplished with C++ before the Standard was published.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++17 did change the sequencing with regard to the evaluation of the expressions used to call a function. While it doesn't impose any particular order, [it *does* say](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.call#5):

> The initialization of a parameter, including every associated value computation and side effect, is indeterminately sequenced with respect to that of any other parameter.

"Indeterminately sequenced" [is defined as](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/intro.execution#15):

> Evaluations A and B are indeterminately sequenced when either A is sequenced before B or B is sequenced before A, but it is unspecified which.

So one parameter will be initialized before the other, including *all* side-effects. So either the first argument or the second argument is fully evaluated before the other.

Comment: So the call to `processWidget` in the example is no more UB, right?

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion rather than a direct answer to your question.

A principle I would apply to this case: If the safety of a statement is not obvious, then just don't assume it - even if language-lawyering can find you the appropriate guarantee. Code which makes subtle assumptions is usually not a good idea to write. What if someone then tries to compile this with C++14 due to some compatibility constraints? They won't get a warning.

Instead, save yourself the trouble by either using your two-line solution (with std::move), or write a version of `make_shared()` which also takes the custom deleter - probably something like this:

```
template< class T, class Deleter, class... Args >
shared_ptr<T> make_shared_with_deleter( Deleter d, Args&&... args )
{
    return std::shared_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward(args)...), d );
}
```

and then call:

```
processWidget(nonstd::make_shared_with_deleter<Widget>(cusDel), computePriority());
```

See also the same argument regarding [tuple destruction order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39068744/1593077).

Comment: The whole point of standardizing evaluation of parameters is to make sure that people *can* rely on it, so that they *don't have* to write such functions.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Actually, I would try to avoid use raw `new` in the middle of some long expression anyway. Standardizing certain subtleties may have some benefits, but relying on such subtleties is still not necessarily good practice.

Comment: It's not about `new` specifically. It could be any function call or evaluation. Consider pack expansions or fold expressions over range expressions. Without some basic guarantees about evaluation sequencing, you wouldn't be able to effectively use them.