# Are there non-trivial differences between EASTL and libc++'s std::tuple?

Tags: c++, std, libc++, stdtuple, eastl

We know that libc++ and libstdc++'s `std::tuple` implementations are very different - forwards vs backwards order of element storage:

[Why does libstdc++ store std::tuple elements in reverse order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27663641/why-does-libstdc-store-stdtuple-elements-in-reverse-order)

However, EASTL's tuple class [says, in a comment](https://github.com/electronicarts/EASTL/blob/master/include/EASTL/tuple.h), that its implementation is based on libc++'s. It doesn't say, however, if there are any non-trivial changes or whether it's a straightforward import into EASTL (depending on EASTL's versions of `<type_traits>`, `<functional>` etc.).

So, which is it? And - if there is a significant difference, why was it introduced?