# Why aren't all these tuples the same size

Tags: c++, memory-layout

I'm interested in having tuples with "holes" in them. These holes are an empty struct. All holes will have the same type, called `Empty` here.

For illustration purposes, let

```cpp
struct DByte {
    std::array<std::byte, 2> data;
};

struct Empty {
};
```

. As I expected,

```cpp
sizeof(std::tuple<DByte, Empty, Empty>) = 2
```

. However,

```cpp
sizeof(std::tuple<Empty, DByte, Empty>) = 3
sizeof(std::tuple<Empty, Empty, DByte>) = 3
```

and I can't understand why these last two types aren't of size 2 (on a platform with `sizeof(std::byte) == 1 && alignof(std::byte) == 1`).

[This demonstration](https://godbolt.org/z/5h9fbx4Wz) also prints the memory layout of these types under Clang and GCC.

Why aren't all these tuples the same size with the following layout:

```
0       1       2
|     DByte     |
| Empty | Empty |
```

?

Comment: they dont have that layout. Just recently heard a talk that mentioned one implementation that keeps the tuples elements in reverse order, it can be different

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27663641/why-does-libstdc-store-stdtuple-elements-in-reverse-order

Comment: Notice that MSVC is "coherent" with always 4 [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fE1hnKPx6).

Comment: Notice that you have similar result with regular struct member [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3ofW4f4z6) (With `[[no_unique_address]]`).

Comment: "*As I expected,*" I wouldn't expect that. In fact, I'm pretty sure that `2` is the *wrong answer* for it. That the compiler is violating the specification.

Comment: @NicolBolas can you elaborate on what you mean by "the compiler is violating the specification"?

Answer (score 3):

> Why aren't all these tuples the same size with the following layout:

Because the implementations of `std::tuple` do not re-order their sub objects based on the types of the contained objects (although they are not required to not do so). They use one order that depends on the order of parameters, but not on the types of those parameters.

Normally, all sub objects are required by the standard to have a unique address, and there may not be overlap between sub objects of a standard layout class. There is an exception<sup>1</sup> for empty base classes, which are not required to have a unique address, and that special rule is what some `std::tuple` implementations take advantage of to make empty sub objects use no memory. But it only works when the order of the sub objects is correct for the exception to apply.

<sup>1</sup> C++20 adds another exception, but the standard libraries implemented `std::tuple` in C++11 and cannot practically change their layout without breaking ABI, so that is not important to the implementation of `std::tuple`. The C++20 feature wouldn't improve the optimisation without re-ordering the sub objects either.

Comment: I think `std::tuple` might reorder. Its layout is not specified.

Comment: @Jarod42 Sure. I didn't say they aren't allowed to nor that they won't. I said that they don't.

Answer (score 0):

> Why aren't all these tuples the same size with the following layout:

They might have, it is just a optimization miss.

You might see the same miss for regular classes:

```
struct A
{
    [[no_unique_address]]DByte m;
    [[no_unique_address]]Empty e1;
    [[no_unique_address]]Empty e2;
};

struct B
{
    [[no_unique_address]]Empty e1;
    [[no_unique_address]]DByte m;
    [[no_unique_address]]Empty e2;
};

struct C
{
    [[no_unique_address]]Empty e1;
    [[no_unique_address]]Empty e2;
    [[no_unique_address]]DByte m;
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zvco4P55d)

Notice that msvc gives same size for your different tuples [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fE1hnKPx6). (always 4, so without empty class optimization).

Layout of tuple is not specified. So all those are possible.