# What's the point of template specialization in C++ if you can do the same without templates?

Tags: c++

Here is a simple example:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
void print(T in){ 
  printf("NOT printing int\n"); 
}

template <> // <-- template specialization
void print<int>(int in){ 
  printf("printing int\n"); 
}

int main(){
 print(5); // printing int
 return 0;
}
```

But the `int` version can be written without even using templates, like this:

```
void print(int in){ 
  printf("printing int\n"); 
}
```

So what the point of template specialization here?

#### Edit (example of where it might be needed)

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
void print(){ 
  printf("printing float\n"); 
}

template <> 
void print<int>(){ 
  printf("printing int\n"); 
}

int main(){
 print<float>();
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Think about the returnvalue.

Comment: For functions, overloads are generally preferred over specialization indeed. but there is also specialization for classes (such as traits).

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Let's say that template specialization is not useful in this particular case. It could still be useful in other places.

Comment: Such templates could still be conveniently used in other ones, which only pass type parameters through.

Comment: could you give an example of the other places?

Comment: I believe I just did.

Comment: When selecting a template instantiation the non-specialized version won't be considered.

Comment: Now try to write a recursive template class. Like, oh, std::tuple. Without specialization.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: `std::tuple` doesn't require recursion AFAIR.

Comment: There are *many, many* uses of template specializations. The question is way too broad at the moment.

Comment: I would be very curious to see your compiler's header files' implementation of std::tuple (it's all there in the header files) that does not use recursion and a specialization for std::tuple<>, @jarod42

Comment: *Function* template specialisation is often advised against by C++ gurus. Class template specialisation is a totally different matter.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: [why-is-it-not-good-to-use-recursive-inheritance-for-stdtuple-implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9641699/why-is-it-not-good-to-use-recursive-inheritance-for-stdtuple-implementations) provides [link](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/tuple) to implementation. After a quick view, there is a specialization for empty tuple though, but I don't see recursion.

Comment: @Jarod42 tuple's Base_T inherits from tuple_impl, which inherits from `public __tuple_leaf<_Indx, _Tp>...`, the recursion is in setting up this parameter pack. The template itself is not recursive, but its class member gets constructed with the help of a recursive helper tempalte. I repeat: good luck implementing `std::tuple` without recursion.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: compiler might provide intrinsic for `index_sequence` (to avoid recursion and so have only 1 instantiation instead of naive `O(N)` or better `O(log(N))` depth recursion. But anyway `tuple`/`index_sequence` are not recursive per se.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that you cannot do everything with overloads. Consider for example a case where there is no argument:

```
template<class T>
void foo();
```

There is no way to overload this function because there are no arguments. But it can be called with explicit instantiation:

```
foo<int>();
```

And those instantiations can be specialised.

Then there are class template specialisations which of course cannot be done using function overloading.

---

There is some overlap between what can be done with overloads and what can be done with template specialisation. It's typically considered better to use an overload when it is an option.

Comment: `std::type_identity<T>` might serve as tag to allow to have argument though.