# human-readable type_info.name()

Tags: c++, typeid

I've compiled the following code with `g++`, and got output, which written in comments.

```
template<class T>
void foo(T t) { cout << typeid(t).name() << endl; }

int main() {
    foo("f");       //emits "PKc"
    foo(string());  //emits "Ss"
}
```

I know, that `type_info.name()` isn't standartized, but is there any way to get human-readable results?

Something like the following would be good enought

```
const char *
class string
```

Comment: Unless someone knows an update to the standard I'm not aware of, `typeid` is implementation defined, and as such so are the values it returns. If this is no longer the case I'm very curious to know more about it as well. Until then, the mangling algorithm specific to your compiler will likely lead you to the answer (and demangling) you're looking for.

Comment: It's wholly implementation dependent. Microsoft's cl will use names similar to what you're expecting though.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81870/is-it-possible-to-print-a-variables-type-in-standard-c

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use [abi::__cxa_demangle](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.3/a01696.html) for that (demangle function taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9640256/define-multiple-methods-with-parameters-from-variadic-templates)), just remember that the caller is responsible for freeing the return:

```
#include <cxxabi.h>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <cstdlib>

std::string demangle(const char* mangled)
{
      int status;
      std::unique_ptr<char[], void (*)(void*)> result(
        abi::__cxa_demangle(mangled, 0, 0, &status), std::free);
      return result.get() ? std::string(result.get()) : "error occurred";
}

template<class T>
void foo(T t) { std::cout << demangle(typeid(t).name()) << std::endl; }

int main() {
    foo("f");            //char const*
    foo(std::string());  //std::string
}
```

Example on [ideone](http://ideone.com/L3T3p).

Comment: This is not working on mingw g++, the program is dying without throwing any error