# Strange output of std::typeid::name()

Tags: c++, typeinfo

I used `typeid` to get the type names of the std::vector::size_type and a zero sized class A with the following code ([cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid)):

```
#include<iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

class A {};

int main()
{
    vector<int> v(10); 

    vector<int>::size_type s = v.size(); 

    A a; 

    cout << typeid(s).name() << endl;
    cout << typeid(a).name() << endl;

};
```

And I got this as output:

```
m
1A
```

I guess that "1" before "A" is a result of the Empty Base Class Optimization, but what does "m" stand for and is this normal?

I am using the following gcc version: g++ (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1) 4.4.3

Comment: The names returned by `type_info::name` are implementation defined. Gcc chose `m` for `size_type`. Beats me :)

Comment: @jrok ah, alrighty then. :)

Comment: You might want to check a reference on the [`std::type_info::name`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name) function.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I did, but I guess I was expecting something better, than a mere "m" character. :)

Comment: The "1" before the "A" is because that's the length of the name `A`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [human-readable type\_info.name()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877521/human-readable-type-info-name)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

G++ uses implementation-defined naming for the types, but it also offers the utility `c++filt` to make them human-readable:

```
$ ./test | c++filt -t
unsigned long
A
```

Comment: So, the name "m" is then reserved and fixed for vector<int>::size_type (for g++)?

Comment: @tomislav-maric the name "m" stands for `unsigned long`, which happens to be typedef for `std::size_t`, which happens to be the typedef for `std::vector<>::size_type`. Typedefs do not create new types.

Comment: I know they don't create new types, I meant this: is "m" then for G++ a name for "unsigned_long", and it is defined somewhere (compiler implementation?), so c++filt looks it up there, and maps it back to "unsigned_long"?

Comment: @tomislav-maric Yes, `/usr/bin/g++` and `/usr/bin/c++filt` are part of the same compiler implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The quick hack I use on gcc to check types is a templated function with a forwarding reference parameter, printing `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`:

```cpp
template<typename T>
void PrintType(T&&) {
    cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
}
```

This might print something like:

> void PrintType(T&&) [with T = long unsigned int]