# using std::string::find to find a longer string in a small one

Tags: c++, string

From this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string const s = "Thisisastring";
    std::string const ss = "Thisisastringg";
    std::string const sss = "Thisisastrin";
    auto p = ss.find(s);
    std::cout << "p:" << typeid(p).name() << "\np =" << p << std::endl;
    auto pp = sss.find(s);
    std::cout << "pp:" << typeid(pp).name() << "\npp =" << pp << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following output:

```
p:m
p =0
pp:m
pp =18446744073709551615
```

Questions:

- From [this link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find), `p` should have the type `size_type` against `m`?
- What does the value of `pp` means? An overflow?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos

Comment: [This link explains the `m`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16396304/strange-output-of-stdtypeidname).

Comment: @KenY-N Thanks. You give me what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`size_type` is not a type by itself, it is an alias defined as follow:

```
typedef Allocator::size_type size_type; // until c++11
typedef std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::size_type size_type; // since c++11
```

Since you are using `std::string`, the allocator is [`std::allocator<char>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator) and thus `size_type` is [`std::size_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t).

The return value of [`std::type_info::name`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name) is implementation defined, and `m` is what your compiler (presumably g++) chose to use for `std::size_t`.

The return value of [`std::basic_string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) when the substring is not found is [`std::basic_string::npos`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos), which is defined as:

```
static const size_type npos = -1;
```

In your case, it comes down to:

```
static const std::size_t npos = -1;
// which is (due to arithmetic modulo 2^n):
static const std::size_t npos = std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max();
```

And with your compiler, the resulting value is `18446744073709551615` which is `2^64 - 1` because `std::size_t` is probably a 64-bits value on your computer. This is **a possible value**, `std::size_t` is not required to be 64-bits long.

You should always test the return value of `std::basic_string::find` (and other related functions) against `std::basic_string::npos` directly.

Comment: Ummm, `size_t` is required to be an unsigned integral type, and unsigned integral types follow the rules of modular arithmetic.  The only thing that can vary is the number of bits.

Answer (score 4):

The value of pp equal to **string::npos** (2^64-1 = 18446744073709551615). That is, the string is not found, **not an overflow**.

The **string.find(...)** method returns any of the followings

1. If the string is matched, it return the position of the first character of the first match.
2. If no matches were found, it returns string::npos

where **npos** is a static member constant value with the greatest possible value for an element of type **size_t** (an unsigned integral type).

To verify it print the string::npos

```
std::cout << std::string::npos << std::endl;
```