# Linked list with compile time checks in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to implement a linked list with compile time checks for in and out capabilities. These capabilities (or caps) shall provide information wether a valid linking can take place.
Therefore the **out** caps of an element are intersected with the **in** caps of the next element. If a valid intersection can be found, the link is established. Please see provided code for such kind of check at runtime.

While this is rather easy to accomplish at runtime, i do not know the direction for meta/template programming to handle it at compile time.
I already started reading into std::variant<>, std::visit<>, template instantiation, template specialization.

Basically, i know about meta/template programming, but only on a pre C++11 level. Please let me ask this open question, how and if this is feasible with meta/template programming.

Thanks in advance.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <list>

enum class NodeType {
    Type1,
    Type2,
    Type3
};

class Caps {
public:
    NodeType type;
    int      minValue;
    int      maxValue;
};

bool intersect(const std::list<Caps>& in, const std::list<Caps>& out)
{
    for (auto i : in) {
        for (auto o : out) {
            if (i.type == o.type) {
                auto minValue = std::max(i.minValue, o.minValue);
                auto maxValue = std::min(i.maxValue, o.maxValue);
                if (maxValue >= minValue) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}

class Node
{
public:
    virtual bool link(Node& next) {
        if (intersect(this->outCaps(), next.inCaps())) {
            m_next = &next;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    virtual std::list<Caps> inCaps() { return {}; }
    virtual std::list<Caps> outCaps() { return {}; }

protected:
    Node* m_next = nullptr;
};

class DerivedNode1 : public Node
{
public:
    std::list<Caps> outCaps() override {
        return { { NodeType::Type1, 1, 10 },
                 { NodeType::Type2, 5, 20 } };
    }
};

class DerivedNode2 : public Node
{
    std::list<Caps> inCaps() override { return { { NodeType::Type1, 8, 12 } }; }
};

class DerivedNode3 : public Node
{
    std::list<Caps> inCaps() override { return { { NodeType::Type2, 1, 4 } }; }
};

class DerivedNode4 : public Node
{
    std::list<Caps> inCaps() override { return { { NodeType::Type3, 1, 99 } }; }
};

int main()
{
    DerivedNode1 node1;
    DerivedNode2 node2;
    DerivedNode3 node3;
    DerivedNode4 node4;

    assert(node1.link(node2));  // This shall link due to matching types and ranges
    assert(!node1.link(node3)); // This shall fail due to non-matching range for a specific type
    assert(!node1.link(node4)); // This shall fail due to non-matching types
}
```

Comment: What is `OUT_CAPS`? What is `IN_CAPS`? What is `Caps`? What are they supposed to be doing? What's `Type1`? What's `MinValue1`? Etc. Please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), and also please learn how to create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: I don't know if I understand you correctly. If you can use c++20 [constraints and concepts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) could be what you want.

Comment: `link` is a virtual function. It will loose the type information of the parameter since it accepts a `Node&`. It's not really clear exactly how you want this to work.

Comment: `std::list` is usually the wrong thing to use for anything, and in this case specifically it makes it impossible. Don't use `std::list` unless you can clearly state why you need to do so. Use a container that is constexpr, make `intersect` constexpr, make `link` a template that is enabled only if the intersection test succeeds.

Comment: It is easy to equip nodes with compile time capabilities. Putting nodes with different capabilities in the same list without forgetting which node has which capability is significantly less so. The list of capabilities of each node, *in order*, must be baked into the type of the list. Adding or removing a node changes the type of the list. Are you sure you need this? What do you need it *for*?

Comment: @KubaOber Ok, the the only remaining container is std::array?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. there is no need to store the caps. Also adding and removing (at a later point) will not happen. The idea is to create a media processing pipeline, that does preliminary checks at compile time. This is loosely inspired by GStreamer.

Comment: So what you have is more like a tuple than like a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below does what you presumably want. If you don't like the `Link` class, `Node::link2` could be renamed to `Node::link`, but otherwise [it needs to have a different name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313063/request-for-member-is-ambiguous-in-g).

You can use either `Node::link2(a, b)` or `a.link(b)` syntax depending on what you prefer. The former doesn't need injection of the single-argument `link` method to derived classes, so may be preferable. The latter requires a bit more work for deep derivation to work

```
// Wouldn't work because `DerivedNodeY::link` and `DerivedNodeX::link` are ambiguous;
class DerivedNodeX : public DerivedNodeY, Link<DerivedNodeX>
{
public:
    static constexpr std::array<Caps,1> inCaps() { ... }
    // but this makes it work:
    using Link<DerivedNodeX>::link;
};
```

Without the `Link` class, a derived node looks simply like:

```
class DerivedNode : public Node
{
public:
    static constexpr std::array<Caps,1> inCaps() {
        return {{ { NodeType::Type3, 1, 99 } }};
    }
};
```

The code is C++17, it compiles with gcc and clang, but it crashes MSVC (up to 19.22) with an internal error :(. Kudos for writing a nice compiler testcase!

```
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>

enum class NodeType {
    Type1,
    Type2,
    Type3
};

struct Caps {
    NodeType type;
    int      minValue;
    int      maxValue;
};

class Node
{
public:
    static constexpr std::array<Caps,0> inCaps() { return {}; }
    static constexpr std::array<Caps,0> outCaps() { return {}; }

    template <class InCaps, class OutCaps>
    static constexpr bool intersect(const InCaps &in, const OutCaps &out);

    template <class N1, class N2>
    static std::enable_if_t<
        std::is_base_of_v<Node, N1> &&
        std::is_base_of_v<Node, N2> &&
        intersect(N1::outCaps(), N2::inCaps()), void>
    link2(N1 &prev, N2 &next) {
        prev.m_next = &next;
    }

protected:
    Node* m_next = nullptr;
};

template <typename ThisNode>
class Link
{
public:
    template <class N2> void link(N2 &next) {
        Node::link2(*static_cast<ThisNode*>(this), next);
    }
};

template <class InCaps, class OutCaps>
constexpr bool Node::intersect(const InCaps &in, const OutCaps &out)
{
    for (auto i : in) {
        for (auto o : out) {
            if (i.type == o.type) {
                auto minValue = std::max(i.minValue, o.minValue);
                auto maxValue = std::min(i.maxValue, o.maxValue);
                if (maxValue >= minValue) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

class DerivedNode1 : public Node, public Link<DerivedNode1>
{
public:
    static constexpr std::array<Caps,2> outCaps() {
        return {{ { NodeType::Type1, 1, 10 },
                  { NodeType::Type2, 5, 20 } }};
    }
};

class DerivedNode2 : public Node, public Link<DerivedNode2>
{
public:
    static constexpr std::array<Caps,1> inCaps() {
        return {{ { NodeType::Type1, 8, 12 } }};
    }
};

class DerivedNode3 : public Node, public Link<DerivedNode3>
{
public:
    static constexpr std::array<Caps,1> inCaps() {
        return {{ { NodeType::Type2, 1, 4 } }};
    }
};

class DerivedNode4 : public Node, public Link<DerivedNode4>
{
public:
    static constexpr std::array<Caps,1> inCaps() {
        return {{ { NodeType::Type3, 1, 99 } }};
    }
};

int main()
{
    DerivedNode1 node1;
    DerivedNode2 node2;
    DerivedNode3 node3;
    DerivedNode4 node4;

    Node::link2(node1, node2); // compiles
    node1.link(node2);
#if 0
    Node::link2(node1, node3); // fails to compile
    node1.link(node3);
    Node::link2(node1, node4); // fails to compile
    node1.link(node3);
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ doesn't have proper intersection types. But you can fake it a bit with compile-time template logic.

Say I define some capabilities as mixins:

```cpp
struct cap_a {
    void foo();
};
struct cap_b {
    void bar();
};
struct cap_c {
    void baz();
};
```

And a container like this that inherits from all the capabilities:

```cpp
template<typename... TCaps>
struct intersectable : public TCaps... {};
```

I can create an intersection of two `intersectable`'s with a mix of SFINAE and variadic templates. The resulting type only has capabilities that both inputs have.

First step of doing a cross-join is to check if a type is in a list. This is a pretty basic variadic macro. Each iteration pops off a type, checks if its the target type, and or's it with the next iteration.

```cpp
template<typename TCap, typename... TCaps>
struct has_capability_impl;

template<typename TCap, typename TCapFirst, typename... TCaps>
struct has_capability_impl<TCap, TCapFirst, TCaps...> {
    static constexpr bool value = std::is_convertible<TCap, TCapFirst>::value || has_capability_impl<TCap, TCaps...>::value;
};

template<typename TCap>
struct has_capability_impl<TCap> {
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};

template<typename TCap, typename... TCaps>
constexpr bool has_capability = has_capability_impl<TCap, TCaps...>::value;
```

You can do this with fold expressions in C++17, but this works in older versions.

Next is the intersection. This a template with 3 types: An empty result itersectable, the left hand side, and branches with enable_if. If the type is present on the right intersectable, move the type over to the result in the inherited base type. OTherwise, don't.

For each iteration, pop a type off a

```cpp
template<typename TLRhs, typename TLhs, typename TRhs, typename = void> 
struct intersect_impl;

template<typename... TLRCaps, typename TFirst, typename... TLCaps, typename... TRCaps>
struct intersect_impl<intersectable<TLRCaps...>, intersectable<TFirst, TLCaps...>, intersectable<TRCaps...>, std::enable_if_t<has_capability<TFirst, TRCaps...>>> : intersect_impl<intersectable<TLRCaps..., TFirst>, intersectable<TLCaps...>, intersectable<TRCaps...>> { };

template<typename... TLRCaps, typename TFirst, typename... TLCaps, typename... TRCaps>
struct intersect_impl<intersectable<TLRCaps...>, intersectable<TFirst, TLCaps...>, intersectable<TRCaps...>, std::enable_if_t<!has_capability<TFirst, TRCaps...>>> : intersect_impl<intersectable<TLRCaps...>, intersectable<TLCaps...>, intersectable<TRCaps...>> { };
```

By the time there are no types left on the left hand side, the result only has capabilities present from both sides:

```cpp
template<typename... TLRCaps, typename... TRCaps>
struct intersect_impl<intersectable<TLRCaps...>, intersectable<>, intersectable<TRCaps...>> {
    using type = intersectable<TLRCaps...>;
};

template<typename TLhs, typename TRhs>
using intersection = typename intersect_impl<intersectable<>, TLhs, TRhs, void>::type;
```

Package that in a trivial function to combine instances:

```cpp
template<typename TLhs, typename TRhs>
intersection<TLhs, TRhs> intersect(TLhs lhs, TRhs rhs) {
    return intersection<TLhs, TRhs>{}; // runtime link logic goes here
}
```

...and the result is type-safe capability intersections:

```cpp
int main() {
    intersectable<cap_a, cap_c> ac;
    ac.foo();
    ac.baz();

    intersectable<cap_a, cap_b> ab;
    ab.foo();
    ab.bar();

    auto a = intersect(ac, ab);
    a.foo();
    a.bar(); // error
    a.baz(); // error
}
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/-kd2Qj

Again, this doesn't actually do anything, it just intersects the types. But you can use something like this to make your linked list logic type-safe.

Anyway, to add range checking, it's just a matter of working in compile-time properties for range into the definition of `intersectable`

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>
#include <unordered_set>

struct cap_a {
    void foo();
};
struct cap_b {
    void bar();
};
struct cap_c {
    void baz();
};

template<int Min, int Max, typename... TCaps>
struct intersectable : public TCaps... {
};

template<typename TCap, typename... TCaps>
struct has_capability_impl;

template<typename TCap, typename TCapFirst, typename... TCaps>
struct has_capability_impl<TCap, TCapFirst, TCaps...> {
    static constexpr bool value = std::is_convertible<TCap, TCapFirst>::value || has_capability_impl<TCap, TCaps...>::value;
};

template<typename TCap>
struct has_capability_impl<TCap> {
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};

template<typename TCap, typename... TCaps>
constexpr bool has_capability = has_capability_impl<TCap, TCaps...>::value;

template<typename TLRhs, typename TLhs, typename TRhs, typename = void> 
struct intersect_impl;

template<int LRMin, int LRMax, int LMin, int LMax, int RMin, int RMax, typename... TLRCaps, typename TFirst, typename... TLCaps, typename... TRCaps>
struct intersect_impl<
    intersectable<LRMin, LRMax, TLRCaps...>, 
    intersectable<LMin, LMax, TFirst, TLCaps...>, 
    intersectable<RMin, RMax, TRCaps...>, 
    std::enable_if_t<(has_capability<TFirst, TRCaps...>)>> 
    : intersect_impl<
        intersectable<LRMin, LRMax, TLRCaps..., TFirst>, 
        intersectable<LMin, LMax, TLCaps...>,
        intersectable<RMin, RMax, TRCaps...>> { };

template<int LRMin, int LRMax, int LMin, int LMax, int RMin, int RMax, typename... TLRCaps, typename TFirst, typename... TLCaps, typename... TRCaps>
struct intersect_impl<
    intersectable<LRMin, LRMax, TLRCaps...>, 
    intersectable<LMin, LMax, TFirst, TLCaps...>, 
    intersectable<RMin, RMax, TRCaps...>, 
    std::enable_if_t<(!has_capability<TFirst, TRCaps...>)>>
    : intersect_impl<
        intersectable<LRMin, LRMax, TLRCaps...>, 
        intersectable<LMin, LMax, TLCaps...>, 
        intersectable<RMin, RMax, TRCaps...>> { };

template<int LMin, int LMax, int RMin, int RMax, typename TResult, typename... TRCaps>
struct intersect_impl<TResult, intersectable<LMin, LMax>, intersectable<RMin, RMax, TRCaps...>> {
    using type = TResult;
};

template <typename T>
struct props;

template<int Min, int Max, typename... Caps>
struct props<intersectable<Min, Max, Caps...>> {
    static constexpr int min = Min;
    static constexpr int max = Max;
};

template<typename TLhs, typename TRhs>
using intersection = typename intersect_impl<
    intersectable<(std::max(props<TLhs>::min, props<TRhs>::min)), (std::min(props<TLhs>::max, props<TRhs>::max))>, 
    TLhs, 
    TRhs>::type;

template<typename TLhs, typename TRhs>
intersection<TLhs, TRhs> intersect(TLhs lhs, TRhs rhs) {
    static_assert((props<TLhs>::max >= props<TRhs>::min && props<TLhs>::min <= props<TRhs>::max)  || 
                  (props<TRhs>::max >= props<TLhs>::min && props<TRhs>::min <= props<TLhs>::max), "out of range");
    return intersection<TLhs, TRhs>{}; // runtime intersection logic?
}

int main() {
    intersectable<1, 5, cap_a, cap_c> ac;
    ac.foo();
    ac.baz();

    intersectable<3, 8, cap_a, cap_b> ab;
    ab.foo();
    ab.bar();

    auto a = intersect(ac, ab); // result is a intersectable<3, 5, cap_a>
    a.foo();
    a.bar(); // error
    a.baz(); // error

    intersectable<10, 15, cap_a, cap_b> ab_out_of_range;
    auto a0 = intersect(ac, ab_out_of_range);
}
```

demo: https://godbolt.org/z/zz9-Vg